# Regular Expression to fetch the result between two tags in Java

Tags: java, html, regex

I have an HTML page and I want to fetch the result between two tags `<b>` and `<BR>`:

```
<b>Defendants Name:</b>Donahue, Leah A                                  <BR>
```

What is the regular expression to fetch the words between these two tags?

Comment: You question is unclear: what tag's? What is the exact string to match?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sir Input is like this 
 <b>Defendants Name:</b>Donahue, Leah A                                  <BR>
      <b>A.K.A.:</b>                                                          <BR>
and I want output like this 

means I want the string 
Address:</b> 8904 Arrowcreek Dr                                    
City/State/ZIP:</b> Oregonia, Oh 45054

Comment: Was just about to go find this post... Though if the input is (and always will be) as basic as the example a regex may work here. Probably still a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
    String str = "<b>Defendants Name:</b>Donahue, Leah A                                                    <BR>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<b>(.*)<BR>.*", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (m.matches() == true)
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

And should print

"Defendants Name:Donahue, Leah A                                  "  (excluding the quotes).

Comment: I am not sure this will work, as it may match multiple lines inside the `(.*)`.  You could try `([^\n]*)` to make sure it cannot match more than one line...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use regexps for parsing HTML, use an HTML parser instead. Have a look at [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Comment: @moilejter XPath is for XML. HTML is not XML, as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558502/108326.