# Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?

Tags: html, tags

Is it necessary to write `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

For example, I can make such a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <script src="js/head_script.js"></script><!-- this script will be in head //-->


<div>Some html</div> <!-- here body starts //-->

    <script src="js/body_script.js"></script>
```

And [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) correctly separates head and body:

[image]

The [W3C validator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service) says it's valid.

But I rarely see this practice on the web.

Is there a reason to write these tags?

Comment: The HTML5 validator at https://html5.validator.nu/ requires the `title` tag.  This is the smallest document it considers valid: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>A</title>`

Comment: @bonh And this is the smallest document it considers fully valid (without errors *nor warnings*): `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=""><title>x</title>`

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Omitting the `html`, `head`, and `body` *tags* is certainly allowed by the HTML specifications. The underlying reason is that browsers have always sought to be consistent with existing web pages, and the very early versions of HTML didn't define those elements. When HTML first did, it was done in a way that the tags would be inferred when missing.

I often find it convenient to omit the tags when prototyping and especially when writing test cases as it helps keep the markup focused on the test in question. The inference process *should* create the elements in exactly the manner that you see in Firebug, and browsers are pretty consistent in doing that.

But...

[Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) has at least one known bug in this area. Even [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) exhibits this. Suppose the markup is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test case</title>
<form action='#'>
   <input name="var1">
</form>
```

You should (and do in other browsers) get a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) that looks like this:

```
HTML
    HEAD
        TITLE
    BODY
        FORM action="#"
            INPUT name="var1"
```

But in Internet Explorer you get this:

```
HTML
    HEAD
       TITLE
       FORM action="#"
           BODY
               INPUT name="var1"
    BODY
```

[See it for yourself.](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3ETest%20case%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3Cform%20action%3D%22%23%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cinput%20name%3D%22var1%22%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fform%3E%0D%0A)

This bug seems limited to the `form` start tag preceding any text content and any `body` start tag.

Comment: HTML 1.0 defined HTML, HEAD and BODY: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt

Comment: @Liza - Well it's arguable whether that document defines HTML 1.0, but I stand corrected, that the elements pre-date HTML 2.0. Thanks. However, see http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html from 1992. The elements don't exist then.

Comment: This bug seems not to affect Internet Explorer 11 (I did also test IE8 which I confirm is affected)

Comment: @Yørn - Correct. IE10 and later use an HTML5 compliant parser, which eliminated the issue.

Comment: @Alohci for some reason the error only happens when I use: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/ . Thanks for checking it.

Comment: this answer has no clue.  while yes you can leave them out, but its certain conditions that apply.  html start tag if first thing is not a comment, html end tag if not immediately followed by a comment...  head start if element is empty or if first thing is an element.  head end tag if its not immediately followed by a space or a comment... and a body start tag if its empty or is not a space or comment, and body end tag if it is not followed by a comment...

So, yes you CAN leave them out, under those certain conditions.  But there's no benefit to doing so in reality.

Comment: @Justin - Those restrictions are largely technical and won't ordinarily affect you. So yes, if it matters to your page whether a comment node or white space appears just before the head element or just inside it, (the page's JS *could* depend on it) then you must explicitly identify the head start tag to make that relationship correct. But if it doesn't, (and I've never yet written an HTML page where it does) then the head tag will be inferred somewhere sensible and you can safely omit it. Likewise for the other html, head and body tags.

Comment: I can logically use ASP styles tags, or short tags with my PHP -- and safely do so... but it's not standards compliant...  Just because you CAN do something, doesn't mean you should do it...  One should always write these tags for multiple reasons. #1. You aren't relying on a browsers broken functionality to automatically determine where you want stuff to be.  #2.  it makes the markup easier to read... and #3 it's the standard - so why mess with convention?

Comment: @Justin This answer seems to have quite a clue as the question is "Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?" not whether or not it is a good practice. Conventions tend to change... just take a look at the google styleguide... that is a convention which states you *should* omit these tags... :-)

Answer (score 101):

The Google Style Guide for HTML recommends omitting all optional tags.
That includes  `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, `<p>` and `<li>`.

From *[3.1.7 Optional Tags](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags)*:

> For file size optimization and scannability purposes, consider
> omitting optional tags. The HTML5 specification defines what tags can
> be omitted.
>
> (This approach may require a grace period to be established as a wider
> guideline as it’s significantly different from what web developers are
> typically taught. For consistency and simplicity reasons it’s best
> served omitting all optional tags, not just a selection.)
>
> ```
> <!-- Not recommended -->
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Spending money, spending bytes</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <p>Sic.</p>
>   </body>
> </html>
>
> <!-- Recommended -->
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <title>Saving money, saving bytes</title>
> <p>Qed.
> ```

Comment: Example of incompatibility: the live-reload tool I use for web development (puer) automatically inserts a script in head. Without at last the <head> tag, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Offirmo What on Earth is that?

Comment: @KenSharp livereload web dev tools usually work by inserting some code in pages served, like that : `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>`. For exotic templates, they don't understand where they should insert their code.

Comment: @Offirmo The documentation of livereload states you should be adding that script to your client pages yourself. Perhaps you are using a magic library that does it for you. That should be the source of the difficulty you are having.

Comment: So, the Google Style Guide for HTML/CSS also says to indent with 2 spaces [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Indentation#Indentation) which means that those tags are not optional, right?  Or no?

Comment: Omitting all possible tags is penny-wise and pound-foolish. The bandwidth savings is a tiny % (especially since most connections auto-compress), while the odds of human error on the edge cases are high (consider authors, editors, and even HTML parser writers). It's also harder to find errors (because of the change in entropy).

Comment: Glad to see this is wrong: https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition

Comment: Not even title is needed. You could set it by Javascript and reload the page. Then crawlers can see there is a title and update to get best SEO of your title. I just read today while tons of info is passing by.

Comment: Interesting that goiogle.com violates the Google Style Guide, because it has <html>.

Comment: The style guide is not saying to remove <p> or <li> tags, but </p> and </li> closing tags **if** there is a correct element (see documentation) immediately following as stated here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission

Comment: @FrankBuss tbf, the html tag there has attributes, but the point was that the `html` tag was extraneous here, not necessarily that it must be always omitted. However it would be better if they included `<html lang=en>`  in the recommended example as it's needed for screen readers but may be overlooked due to this style rule

Answer (score 54):

Contrary to [Liza Daly's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags/5642092#5642092) about HTML5, that specification is actually quite specific about which tags can be omitted, and when (and the rules are a bit different from HTML 4.01, mostly to clarify where ambiguous elements like comments and whitespace belong)

The relevant reference is *[8.1.2.4 Optional tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#optional-tags)*, and it says:

- An *html* element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the *html* element is not a comment.
- An *html* element's end tag may be omitted if the *html* element is not immediately followed by a comment.
- A *head* element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the *head* element is an element.
- A *head* element's end tag may be omitted if the *head* element is not immediately followed by a space character or a comment.
- A *body* element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the *body* element is not a space character or a comment, except if the first thing inside the *body* element is a script or style element.
- A *body* element's end tag may be omitted if the *body* element is not immediately followed by a comment.

So your example is valid HTML5, and would be parsed like this, with the *html*, *head* and *body* tags in their implied positions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <script src="js/head_script.js"></script></HEAD><BODY><!-- this script will be in head //-->


<div>Some HTML content</div> <!-- here body starts //-->

    <script src="js/body_script.js"></script></BODY></HTML>
```

Note that the comment "this script will be in *head*" is actually parsed as part of the *body*, although the script itself is part of the head. According to the specification, if you want that to be different at all, then the `</HEAD>` and `<BODY>` tags may not be omitted. (Although the corresponding `<HEAD>` and `</BODY>` tags still can be.)

Answer (score 20):

It's true that the HTML specifications permit certain tags to be omitted in certain cases, but generally doing so is unwise.

It has two effects - it makes the specification more complex, which in turn makes it harder for browser authors to write correct implementations (as demonstrated by [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) getting it wrong).

This makes the likelihood of browser errors in these parts of the specification high. As a website author, you can avoid the issue by including these tags - so while the specification doesn't say you have to, doing so reduces the chance of things going wrong, which is good engineering practice.

What's more, the latest HTML 5.1 WG specification currently says (bear in mind it’s a work in progress and may yet change).

> A *body* element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or
> if the first thing inside the *body* element is not a space character or
> a comment, except if the first thing inside the *body* element is a
> meta, link, script, style, or template element.

From *[4.3.1 The body element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-body-element)*.

This is a little subtle. You can omit *body* and *head*, and the browser will then infer where those elements should be inserted. This carries the risk of not being explicit, which could cause confusion.

So this

```
<html>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <script ... >
  ...
```

results in the script element being a child of the *body* element, but this

```
<html>
  <script ... >
  <h1>hello</h1>
```

would result in the script tag being a child of the *head* element.

You could be explicit by doing this:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <script ... >
      <h1>hello</h1>
```

and then whichever you have first, the script or the *h1*, they will both, predictably appear in the *body* element. These are things which are easy to overlook while refactoring and debugging code (say for example, you have JavaScript which is looking for the 1st script element in the *body* - in the second snippet it would stop working).

As a general rule, being explicit about things is always better than leaving things open to interpretation. In this regard, [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) is better, because it forces you to be completely explicit about your element structure in your code, which makes it simpler, and therefore less prone to misinterpretation.

So yes, you can omit them and be technically valid, but it is generally unwise to do so.

Comment: IE gets things wrong because the authors couldn't care less about standards. It's their fault if it doesn't work properly. The standards are defined so they should make sure IE works with them.

Comment: @KenSharp I don't disagree, but until you can force all you customers to not use it we're kinda stuck with it. So better to write code which is completely unambiguous rather than rely on everything working as it should.

Comment: Users have been forced to dump IE for years for not being compliant. Nobody expects users to continue to use IE6, even if people are still installing Windows XP. We can't expect to support Windows 3.1 forever either. OSI Level 8 error.

Comment: Exactly which tags can be omitted and exactly where, also varies by HTML version. That also seems like a good reason to avoid them (except for the most obvious and common and consistent cases).

Comment: @TextGeek `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 16):

It's valid to omit them in HTML 4:

> 7.3 The HTML element 
> start tag: optional, End tag: optional 
>
> 7.4.1 The HEAD element 
> start tag: optional, End tag: optional

From *[7 The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html)*.

In HTML5, there are no "required" or "optional" elements exactly, as HTML5 syntax is more loosely defined.  For example, `title`:

> The title element is a required child in most situations, but when a higher-level protocol provides title information, e.g. in the Subject line of an e-mail when HTML is used as an e-mail authoring format, the title element can be omitted.

From *[4.2.2 The title element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-title-element)*.

It's not valid to omit them in true XHTML5, though that is almost never used (versus XHTML-acting-like-HTML5).

However, from a practical standpoint you often want browsers to run in "standards mode," for predictability in rendering HTML and CSS.  Providing a DOCTYPE and a more structured HTML tree will guarantee more predictable cross-browser results.

Comment: Don't muddle elements with tags. See cHao's comments elsewhere on this page. For `html`, `head` and `body`, the elements are mandatory, but the tags are optional.

Comment: Actually you are wrong in the last bit. Tag omission is an SGML DTD feature, all browsers that support SGML parsing(that is all browsers) also support tag omission. The reason why you can't do it in XHTML5 is because it is XML, not SGML. XML is too dumb to infer elements.

Comment: @OdraEncoded Can you provide verification for your statement, please? I do not find that to be the case (see [the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing)).

Comment: @OdraEncoded -- close, but not quite true. Tag omission is an optional feature for SGML parsers (though most support it), as defined in ISO 8879. Nearly all HTML parsers support it, though Python's 'html.parse' appears not to (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954170/beautifulsoup-bs4-parsing-wrong/30083678#30083678).

Comment: @OdraEncoded Re. "XML is too dumb to infer elements" -- That was a conscious design choice when the deep magic was written, made in part so browser vendors could stop putting hundreds of developer-years into trying to outdo each other in recovering bad HTML. With XML there's just one rule about tag omission: "don't". That's easy to understand, test, generate, and parse correctly. Maybe that counts as "dumb", but I don't think so.

Answer (score -5):

Firebug shows this correctly because your *browser* automagically fixes the bad markup for you. This behaviour is not specified anywhere and can (will) vary from browser to browser. Those tags are required by the DOCTYPE you're using and should not be omitted.

The [*HTML* element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element-0) is the root element of every html page. If you look at all other elements' description it says where an element can be used (and almost all elements require either *head* or *body*).

Comment: So, it may be non cross-browser?

Comment: in other words - bad practice yielding undefined results.

Comment: I've just found big site with such markup. Biggest russian search-engine yandex.ru has no html, head and body tags

Comment: @Innuendo Just because something's big doesn't mean that it's well put together.

Comment: Nice example of "How not to do it."

Comment: As an appeal to authority, I find that unconvincing. google.com is invalid HTML as well. Doesn't mean yours should be.

Comment: The elements must exist.  Nothing says the *tags* do.  HTML without html/head/body tags is, in fact, **valid** as long as no element appears where it shouldn't.  (`<title>` after a `<p></p>`, for example.)

Comment: HTML parsing behavior *is* specified in the HTML5 spec, so no, it won't vary from browser to browser.

Comment: @Marjin "HTML parsing behavior" is also specified in every *other* HTML version's spec. And they are slightly different. Browsers also have their own ways of deciding which version of the rules (or their own mix) to use; at least when the document doesn't explicitly say, as it usually doesn't. So behavior most certainly does vary from browser to browser. Fortunately the differences are small, but it's wise to avoid depending on edge cases too much..