# Google doesn't follow W3C standards... whaaa?

Tags: html, validation, w3c, google-search, web-standards

A friend of mine just pointed out an interesting phenomenon... I went to the [Google home page](http://www.google.com/) and looked at the source code:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Google</title>
...
...
...
A LOT OF STUFF HERE
...
...
...
</script>
```

... so I noticed that source code doesn't have the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags. Using Chrome's Inspector, it shows the closing tags but when I right click and look at the source, its not there.

What is going on here? Am I missing something? I tried using the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and it showed a bunch of errors...

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.google.com/

So... what's the deal?

Comment: OMG Google doesn't follow web standards! Stop the presses!

Comment: I'm guessing Google's just trying to save a few bytes for each page load, it's realised that browsers will happily show the page without them and therefore doesn't really care. - they're not using a W3C doctype either.

Comment: The body tag is omittable. The browser can figure out it out without us having to declare it

Comment: @Rich... Yeah I didn't realize that Google cared about optimization at such a level :) Thanks!

Comment: not only google ..you can go through http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Comment: @Test... I know that a lot of pages don't follow standards, I was just surprised that Google didn't close html and body tags

Comment: @Rich: that's the official HTML5 doctype they are using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has a semi-official answer as a [youtube video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBACTS-tyg)

Basically when considering they're handling hundreds of millions of requests, they try to minimise the number of bytes sent per request.  It's a tradeoff between validation, size and compatibility with different browsers used across the web.

Answer (score 2):

No real-world browser actually rejects invalid HTML. Google is more concerned about supporting lots of different browsers, and optimising their home page down to the byte level. Whether they are right to be so pedantic about optimisation, I don't know, but they sure do serve a lot of pages.

Answer (score 2):

See some answers here
[Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

W3C Validation says it's valid. From html 4.
Also In HTML5, there are no "required" or "optional" elements exactly, as HTML5 syntax is more loosely defined.

Comment: "For example, title:"... is something supposed to follow here?

Comment: I was just quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags#answer-5642092 but accidently added some extra text