# HTML5 Validation Error: body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, validation

I was hoping that someone may know how to resolve this HTML5 validation error.  When I try to validate my page:  http://blog.genesispetaluma.com using http://validator.w3.org, it gives me the following error code:

> Error Line 90, Column 63: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

```
<body class="home blog single-author two-column right-sidebar">
```

I interpreted this error to mean that I have two body tags in the code.  However, I have searched everywhere and can only find one `<body>` (the one referenced by the error) and one `</body>`.  Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: sometimes, charset utf-8 with BOM cause this problem.

Comment: Thank you @JanCzarny that was indeed causing it in my case!!  Fixed by changing all my PHP source files in the editor to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM".  Apparently any characters - even invisible ones -  coming at the top of the HTML makes the browser infer a **phantom body element**.

Comment: @Jan Czarny Thanks, that's just solved my problem also. As reference for others, Notepad++ is one useful editor (or other programming editor) to change this in files; just load the file and click the "Encoding" main menu option, then select the "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" option, and resave the file. Job done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly it's because:

```
<div id="wrapFix">

<div id="drawLogo1">
    <div id="drawLogo2">
        <img src="http://genesispetaluma.com/img/logoNew.png" alt="Genesis Fitness G stylelogo">
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of drawLogo1 -->
```

Is between your closing head tag and opening body tag. I.e. lines 81-87

Comment: I had a similar error and I could conclude that if you add a tag that _should_ be inside an element (in this case, `<body>`), the validator will assume that the tag (in this case, the `<div>` tag — an element that should be inside `<body>`) is "of the same type". The validator thinks that `<div>` is `<body>`, hence the error of two `<body>` tags opened.

Comment: Yes. Reading a bit about this issue reveals that the `<body>` tag is not necessary for valid HTML. However, a body _element_ will be inferred based on the markup. So, a browser will (in this case) wrap the `<div>` tag with a body element. And since there is a `<body>` tag later in the markup the validator likely makes the correct judgement that there are two body elements. Further details are available in the answers to this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/355499 (nice comments there aswell)

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem but with `<head>`, giving the following W3C markup error:

> A head start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

I had this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
```

When it was supposed to be:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I knew that was wrong but it's hard to spot sometimes, as you're just so used to the header code being correct 99% of the time. I obviously cut n pasted some code and that ended up in the wrong place.

This isn't specific to your question, I know, as your error relates to the `<body>` tag, but this is the kind of thing you're looking for. Maybe you have a `<link>` or `<meta>` tag in your body somewhere, that's meant to be in the `<head>`. Without seeing your code, it's hard to give you a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

One of the widgets (the facebook like button I believe) you're using is inserting HTML into the page and part of that HTML is a body tag. Not sure if there's anything you can do about this, but I think that's what's throwing the error. Looks like this:

```
<body class="plugin transparent_widget ff4 win Locale_en_US">
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me what line you are seeing that on?  I do a search in the page source and can't find this code.

Comment: If you just do a "view source" in your browser you won't see it because it isn't a part of the html that is downloaded when your browser originally makes the request, it's injected into the document after its initially loaded by the javascript widget. Try using something like firebug for firefox that let's you see the actual rendered html and it will show up.

Comment: It's just inside each div with the class of "entry-content"

Answer (score 1):

I got this error:

> A head start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

I read this post and then i noticed my  tag listed before the head like this.

```
<title>Home</title>
<head>
</head>

it should have been
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens in below said scenarios as per my knowledge -

1. When you mistakenly choose `<head>` thinking `<header>` tag.
2. When your `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<section>` or `<footer>` tag(s) are outside of `<body>` tag.

So, after creating your page, you can validate these changes [here](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message : check out if any body-inside `<element>` is displayed between the `<head>` and `<body>`, like said above.

My error was caused by a `<div>` tag, with absolute position, to display some page information during the development - simply a **line on** a **false position** in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the facebook tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

which was inside the page's `<head>`.

Moved that to the `<body>` of the relevant page (not required globally) sorted it. So yes, the answer supplied above by Emil H was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in my case hgroup tag is the reason why I'm having validation error I, remove this tag from head tag and put it inside after body tag after this the document is now valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I had exactly the same problem and it seems that including some php files within the head element was strangely giving the problem, even if the view-source of Firefox was not printing such php code nor tags

```
<head>
  <? include("./file.php"); ?>
  <title><? echo $title ?></title>
</head>
```

solved using:

```
<? include("./file.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><? echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your problem With head and body both are show validate error just remove displaying text from head and keep it in body..
I have been faces the problem recently.
For Example You have text to display in header inside head just remove header from head and keep it in body ......Problem solved...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also bear in mind, if you copy/paste your code from things like slack, etc. they will have 'special characters' for formatting (that are usually invisible) which may cause that issue.

Here is a video to demonstrate: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJS15zmSvzhVXVLcQGGhePZGNCxWHocN/view

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you put into `<head>` tag that restricted  to be there. For example:

```html
<head>
  <audio preload="auto" class="menu-beep" id="sound-01">
    <source src="sound-01.mp3">         
  </audio>
</head>
```

In this case, the  tag will be immediately opened in the browser memory. But later the browser will find the body tag that opens the page. This is how it turns out that there is a second body tag.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem with `<head>` tag. I use https://validator.w3.org

Look at few examples how to solve this problem:

- **`<script>` should be inside `<head>`**

[image]

- **css should be inside `<head>`**

[image]