# Put CSS in the document head but i don't have a head?

Tags: html, pagespeed

According to google's style guide you should omit optional tags like `<head>`

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Optional_tags

However, doing so causes google pagespeed to tell me:

> CSS in the document body adversely impacts rendering performance.
>   http://site.com has CSS in the document body: 1 style block(s) in the
>   body should be moved to the document head.

Right, so what should be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageSpeed is unreliable in matters like this. You should analyze yourself whether your document structure is correct. Using HTML 4.01 and a validator, you will immediately see whether some `style` element appears inside `body`, since it is a markup error there (though it works there, too).

The page http://site.com that your quote mentions does not have this issue (it is XHTML, with no tag omission). Please post a real URL, or at least use the .example pseudo-domain to signal that a URL is dummy.

Without seeing the actual page, it is impossible to analyze the problem, but in general, Google PageSpeed seems to issue spurious comments. It appears to work inconsistently, but at least in some occasions it clearly parses a document wrong. For example, the following code triggered the message:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>foo</title>
<style></style>
<h1>foo</h1>
```

There is no ambiguity here: the `style` element is in the `head` element (and that’s how browsers parse the document, and search engines don’t really matter here), even though PageSpeed claims otherwise.

I tried adding the omitted tags, with no effect, until suddenly, PageSpeed stopped issuing the message, and now the document above gets a clean report. I conclude that PageSpeed works non-deterministically, possibly due to its aggressive caching.

Comment: thanks I basically have your example. So pagespeed is wrong? Good to know I think.

Answer (score 1):

This link tells you under which **CONDITIONS** some tags may be omitted.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission

But beware, omitting **tag** do not mean omitting **elements**

In your case **<head>** is optional (even html).
Just do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pathTo.css">
```

You may have a look to

[Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

For the readers which may want to experiment,
save the following code to file and read it and check with a tool like firebug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="pathTo.css">
 <script>var a = 0;</script><!-- placed in head -->

 <div>any html text or tags</div>
 <script> var b = 1</script> <!-- placed in body -->
```

Answer (score 0):

From the specification:

> A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or a comment, ***except if the first thing inside the body element is a script or style element.***

This appears to be the most likely cause of your problem, as this makes the starting body tag non-optional.

(This is assuming you followed the instruction to remove ALL optional tags, not just a selection)