# Including a CSS file in a PHP file that is included in a PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php file that doesn't (for now) use any php code, that holds code for the header and main menu that will be used across all pages. The CSS file has no effect, even though I've created a style class for h1. The text "TEST" shows up, but the style is not applied. How do I properly include the CSS file?

mainMenu.php

```
<!--This code is included within the <head> of each page, and the stylesheet for the header and main menu are included here-->
<link href="styles/headerMenu.css" ref="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--Header and menu code-->
<div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
    <?php include ('./includes/mainMenu.php') ?>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and `styles/headerMenu.css` is relative to `index.php` ? The path is correct ? Also you are including in `head` section ..

Comment: Your are shoving `div` tags into the head tag there, also are you sure it is loading the CSS? Check f12 in your browser. Also check that you have applicable rules in your css

Comment: Use a browser debugger to verify the stylesheet is loaded - as pointed out above - this is 99% a problem with the path

Comment: you should use absolute path for the css file.. `/styles/headerMenu.css`

Comment: What are you trying to do? If `mainMenu.php` is itself a full html file, how are you trying to include it in the head of other html/php file. Do check your use case first...

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating a malformed HTML document?

Comment: Hm, HTML newbie here. Definitely made a mistake in trying to use div inside a head. I guess I'm not understanding PHP correctly. I was trying to create a header and menu that is used throughout the site. I figured I would load that in the header but know I now that doesn't work. So how do you recommend that I create menu code once that can be used everywhere?

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: Even that is not "good style", it's not the problem here (browsers handle that with ease). Your problem is the `<link>` tag, you didn't use the right attribute (you mistyped it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/13085111/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS file is not found. Double check the link and correct it:

```
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                        ^- REL not REF
```

Also to prevent additional problems, remove the start and end tags of `<head>` and `<body>` from the code. The way you output the HTML elements, you would create wrong HTML if you keep those tags. Remove them and your page will be valid HTML again.

*index.php*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
    <?php include ('menu.php') ?>    

</html>
```

Valid HTML has the benefit that you can run it through a validator to spot errors early.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because you have got your menu appearing inside your `<head>` tag.

The CSS needs to go inbetween the `<head>` and `</head>` but the rest needs to be inside the `<body>` tag

Comment: The browswer knows that the `<div>` belongs into `<body>` only and will move it there.

Comment: hakre, that is my newbie mistake. I thought div was okay in the head.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: Well, I would not say it's a mistake of you, because you are right: The div should not be placed into the `<head>` section in the first place. It's just with *this* case, that the browser will correct the mistake.

Comment: @hakre just because the browser knows doesn't mean it should not be amended. How can you expect to debug something if not everything is in the correct place to start with? If ShrimpCrackers is learning HTML/PHP, he should learn properly.. not a "ah its ok the browser will fix it".

Comment: @DannyHearnah: Sure, no objection to that. But for learning it's also important (or at least good) to understand the exact cause of a problem. For the standards, please see as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="styles/headerMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This must be at `<HEAD></HEAD>`

```
<div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

This must be at `<BODY></BODY>`

You have to separate this file into 2 files and include them in Head and in Body..

Comment: Thought so as well, but then saw that it is inside the head.

Comment: currently you put both link and div inside the head and THIS is your mistake.. head is for style links and body is for all other html data.

Comment: That is no problem at all, the browser knows that `<div>` can not appear in `<head>` and moves it into the `<body>` automatically. The `<link>` is already within the `<head>` section, so this even if not "correct" is actually "not wrong" and not an issue.

Comment: Its wrong programming if you do mistakes and don't care about them.. 
Such code cant be valid.. and when you dont have valid code you dont know what will happen..

Comment: By the HTML standards, these elements are moved automatically. Even that is the fact, I'm with you that you should not put body-belonging-tags into the head. Just to have a clean HTML writing. However, that is a general advice. And in context of this question: What you outline in your answer even generally not false, is not the answer of the question. The actual error is far more trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13085111/367456

Comment: It doesn't matter that browser will move that elements. ITS VERY UGLY when some developer writes wrong code and he doesn't care about it...

Comment: If you would have read my earlier comment, you would have seen that we share a lot here. I also edited my answer and gave an example how to make the script outputting valid HTML.

Comment: Svetlio, I do care about good code. I'm just new to all this and learning. I mean I just read through some HTML, PHP, and CSS tutorials. I care about good OO design in my C++ and Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include your HTML code in HEAD part. Only include CSS and JavaScript files in HEAD section. and you need to prefix the css or images path in some php file.
 
E.g.
create new php file with name "conn_path.php"

```
<?php
define('SITE_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'siteName/');
define('SITE_HTTP_PATH','http://localhost/'siteName/');
define('CSS_PATH','http://localhost/siteName/styles/');
define('IMAGE_PATH','http://localhost/siteName/images/');
?>
```

And then you path will be like below:-
mainMenu.php

```
<?php include "conn_path.php" ?>
<link href="<?php echo CSS_PATH ;?>headerMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It will help you in whole project…

Answer (score 0):

Create a template file, with your essential (and re-used) html. Also with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags and anything you must have in all pages – As your stylesheets and menu.

Then add a content section with a single variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
    <link href="styles/headerMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Header and menu code-->
    <div>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>

    <?php echo $page_content; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

This way, any page content shoud be assigned to `$page_content` instead of echoed.