# What content can be outside head and body tags?

Tags: html, xhtml

This may seem like a weird question, but i'm building some script that reads HTML files and i'm dividing the content to 2, body and head and was wondering if there could be other content i might not know of?

The only thing i know of is `<DOCTYPE>` and i was wondering if there could be more?

Comment: Unless you are 100% sure the HTML you are reading is 105% complient with standards, it is unsafe to devide the body and the head. As <script> tags can belong in both, and you might stumble on some pages that declare style, title, and whatnot in the body.

Comment: Oh it's ok when i'm saying "dividing" i mean i read from body and head tags

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The doctype declaration isn't exactly content in the sense of the word.

There isn't any content that is supposed to exist outside `head` and `body` (and in fact, any content that's *meant to display* should only exist inside `body`). Browsers can create some pretty wacky DOMs when you give them strange or invalid markup, however. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags/5642982#5642982).

Also, `head` and `body`, in that order, are the only two possible children of `html`, the root element.

Comment: Thanks that answeres the question, but could there be more declarations like doctype?

Comment: There is also the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, though nobody uses that anymore.

Comment: Writing html below the </body></html> tags will teleport it into the body.