# NOT apply css to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have our template designed by a design agency, they delivered us the HTML/CSS template. they have this in their css file:

```
div{
    float: left;
}
```

Now we're implementing a new chat software on the website, which the above line is applying on the chat software and it is ruining all it's css. when I clear the above line the whole template goes ruined up, and when we have it the chat software css is ruined... .
I tried to put the chat software put it after `</body>` and change the above css to:

```
body div{
    float: left;
}
```

But since the chat software is loading some js files, it brings it to the `body` of page and so it's css still not working well.

How I could fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the HTML of the chatbox look like? Or better yet, make a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of your issue.

Comment: *Never* put content outside of the `body`-tag.

Comment: @BramVanroy and why? how about `<script>`

Comment: The best place for scripts are right in front of the closing body-tag, or right before the closing head-tag. Especially older browsers will do some strange DOM stuff when content is placed outside the body-tag. Take a look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470854/what-content-can-be-outside-head-and-body-tags, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags/5642982#5642982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this on that particular chat holding div(element).

```
<div style="float:right" > </div> /*this will move it to right*/
```

or by CSS

```
<div class="chat_holder">
</div>

.class{
    float:right /*or left*/
}
```

If you want to keep it permanent on the bottom of screen on right side as Google mail or other.

```
 <div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;" > </div>
```

or by CSS

```
<div class="chat_holder">
</div>
.class{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

There are many other ways. But without more info i can only help you that much.

Answer (score 1):

you can put chat in a `div` with special ID and set `float:none;` to inner `div`s, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ChatContainer">
    /* chat goes here */
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ChatContainer div{
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: remove `>` before `div` in CSS selector, can you show me your template ?

Answer (score 0):

### You can replace the following:

```
div{
    float: left;
}
```

### with the following:

```
div:not(#chat){
    float: left;
}
```

**Or**

```
div:not([id='chat']){
    float: left;
}
```

Here the `<div>` for the chat-box need to be given the id attribute as `id='chat'`. So your html need to contain the following as the **code of the chat-box**:

```
<div id='chat'>
    code for chatbox.
</div>
```

The solution is based on the method of applying CSS style on all elements except with a specific id. Try it. Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a different `CSS` file for chat software and override the style properties for same.

Or you can also try giving class to your body tag for chat software and use the same `CSS` given below,

body.chatbody div{
    float: left;
}

Comment: Overriding  here is not the solution. This will according to the OP will ruin the template's effects.