# Semantic UI Popup not working inside angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

Just got a problem, i am using semantic-ui to show the popup, but it does not work if i write the code inside any template that reside in ng-view directive, but it will work if i write it outside the ng-view directive, anything wrong with the code?

**This will works**

```
<body>
    <div class="ui container">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Click Me</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.ui.teal.button').popup({
            on: 'click'
        });            
    </script>
</body>
```

**This will not work**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div class="ui container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

<!--sample.html -->
<div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Click Me</div>

 <script>
    $('.ui.teal.button').popup({
        on: 'click'
    });            
 </script>
```

Comment: Well, as I understand it, it's bad practice to put anything that isn't a head or body tag as direct child of the HTML tag.

(see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13470905/2738980 for reference)

Answer (score 0):

When you face a situation where you have to use a directive and at the same time use semantic ui jquery initialization, what you have to do is initalize the sematic ui objects within the directive.

So the First thing that you have to do is, add your button within the ng-view directive. Then make a new directive "showPopUp".

```
<body>
<div class="ui container">
    <div ng-view showPopUp>
      <div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Click Me</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

</script>
```

This is the directive that you have to add to your module.

```
theNameOfYourModule.directive( 'showPopUp', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       $('.ui.teal.button').popup({
        on: 'click'
       });   
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since semantic-ui 2.2 there are css-only popups available:

```
<div>data-tooltip="Add text here"</div>
```

http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/new.html