# HighCharts adding data

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am very new at highcharts. I am trying to make a basic graph showing bitcoin price. However, I'm stuck at the data part.

How do I get the data? And how would hourly, weekly and monthly data represent?

This is what I have till now with me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1h'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '12h'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '24h'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
                },
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                },
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m'
                },
                {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }]
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Vertcoin Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'VTC',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Any and all guidance will be helpful. I could not find any solution / tutorial to help me out.

Comment: @ewolden I can add the data to a csv

Comment: @ewolden How would it work for 1 day, 1 week etc?

Comment: @ewolden Ok. But I think you linked me for high charts, here I am using high stocks?

Comment: @ewolden Can you please share a csv example? I have been trying since last 3 days, but couldn;t make it to work.

Comment: Note: [do not put `<script>` outside `<body>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470854/what-content-can-be-outside-head-and-body-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your chart constructor with all the that you get via `getJSON` function and apply **forced data grouping.** Then you just need to update `dataGrouping.units` when needed (e.g. on button click).

```
$('#months').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataGrouping: {
          units: [
            [
              'month', [1]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/avd0gqgr/

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

**API references:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.line.dataGrouping