# Javascript not running and just printing out entire code on a blank webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Oddly enough i cant see any syntax errors. i am new too javascript but by no means incapable. But whenever i run my code any browser i use just prints out my entire code on a blank webpage without executing any of it. ive never had this problem before. as the codes not being executed i cant use any of the browsers debugging tools.

its not like i haven't started the code properly
the usual old

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

followed by my code and then closing the tags

whats odd is even the above code is being printed on the webpage so its not being recognised as javascript from the very beggining

Has anyone had this problem before? am i missing something

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var die1;           // the 3 dice
var die2;
var die3;

var username;   // users name

var bet  = 0;            // variable for the amount the user bets
var input;              // used to check the bet is a number

var credits = 100;          // users overall credits and starting amount
var round = 0;          // game rounds , will have a maximum of 10 rounds


username = window.prompt("Welcome to Triple Roll! Please enter your name");     // prompts                  the user to enter their name
gamestart;                      // calls the first function to start the game!




var rolldice = function()       // puts all 3 dice rolls into a function to be easily called.
{
die1 = Math.round(Math.random()*6);         // random number generators for the 3 dice
die2 = Math.round(Math.random()*6);         // dieX is an integer (round number) in the  range of 1 to 6
die3 = Math.round(Math.random()*6);
}


var gamestart = function()   // Using this function the game can be reset to starting values, The user is also asked if they would like to hear the rules
{
bet = 0;
credits = 100;
round = 0;

if (window.prompt("Hello" + username ", Do you wish to go over the the instructions?   Y/N ")) = "Yes" || "yes" || "y" || "Y"    // if the user says yes then show rules , else run the game
    { 
confirm(" This game has 10 rounds, at the beginning of the game you will start with 100 credits to bet with. For each round of the game you will bet on the outcome of 3 dice rolls each with numbers 1 through 6. continue?");
confirm(" For each round you may bet between 1 and 100 credits regardless of how many credits you actually have, though be warned if you lose and end up with 0 credits then its game over.");
confirm(" The value of all 3 dice will determine whether or not you win or lose credits, but don't worry , you will be able to see how many credits you have at any time");
confirm(" If the 3 die all show a 1 , then you will win 50 times your bet plus the original stake back, If the 3 die all show the same value other than 1 then you win 30 times your bet plus your original stake back");
confirm("If 2 die show the same value, then you win 8 times your bet plus your original bet. If you don't meet any of the requirements but the values of die add up to 15 or more, then you win 2 times your bet plus the original stake.");
confirm("If one of the die is a 6 or all 3 of the die are odd numbers, then you get your bet back and may try again. In all other situations you lose your bet");
    }
else 
    { 
game;   // call the game function 
    }

}

 var game = function()
{ 
input = window.prompt("Round" + round ". You have" + credits "credits. Please enter a bet between 0-100"); // shows the user what round it is, how many credits they have and asks them to make a bet
bet = parseInt(input);          // checks the input is a number

 if (bet != 0-100);         // if the bet isn't between 0-100
    { 
    game;               // restart the function
    }
else                        // else
    { 
    rolldice;           // call the roll dice function
    }

confirm(" The Die rolls are" + die1 + die2 + die3);     // let user know what the dice values are
    winoutcomes;                // call the function that checks to see if the user has won
```

}

Comment: Can you show a demo of your issue?

Comment: Check if javascript is disabled in your browser!

Comment: Is this a .html file?

Comment: @Grüse That has nothing to do with the price of tea in China

Comment: @RoryPicko92 [Why do u need one?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/561731)

Comment: Have you saved the file with .html or .htm extension?

Comment: Are you sure your not trying to view a `.js` file directly in the browser?

Comment: @StefanDunn again.... Those are not the only 2 web file extentions.... It only has to do with content type and not the extension!

Comment: @Neal I disagree. Put the above plus some js in a file, call it bla.js and open it with your browser.

Comment: i coded this in Notepad ++, ive tried the file as javascript and as html and neither made a difference.

Comment: @Grüse because that would use the javascript content type.

Comment: @StefanDunn Obviously, but if the OP is struggling with executing basic javascript, I hardly doubt any content type issues are to blame.

Comment: @Neal Exactly. That is why I asked the poster in the first place.

Comment: Clarification: is the entire HTML source visible, or only the JavaScript inside the `<script>` block? I assumed the first case, but your comments about "not being recognized as JavaScript" make me suspect the second.

Comment: @Grüse ok since you are going to ask about `.html`, what about: `.htm`, `.php`, `.asp`, `.aspx`... I can go on for a while....

Comment: im not sure how i could demonstrate the issue. as i said i cant see any syntax errors. imagine you had a perfectly fine javascript program, but when you ran it or opened it with a browser, the browser just displays the entire code

Comment: Just show us all the code. Please! Put us out of our misery.

Comment: absolutely everything thats in my program is displayed even the <html> etc at the start

Comment: All I can see is three lines of HTML

Comment: @Neal I was just trying to help by trying an easy fix. But please, go ahead and list all the file extensions you know.

Comment: whenever i copy my code over it just squishes it all together...

Comment: Edit your original question. Don't stick it in a comment.

Comment: Add the rest of you code or this question is going to get closed. And I want to see it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file name is 'xxxxxx.js'

It needs to be 'xxxxx.html'

And it's probably a good idea not to have a space in it too.

So change 'Assignment 01.js' to 'Assignment01.html'

Rename your file.

It will work.

You've just posted some code I see. It doesn't have any close script/body/html tags

Comment: nope, as ive said i have switched between javascript and html and neither file types worked....

Comment: @user2920648 well your image shows you're trying to read a .js file. But you have written an HTML document. That will definitely not work.

Comment: @user2920648 You've just posted some code I see. It doesn't have any </script></body></html> tags

Comment: @user2920648 If you close your script body and html tags after your javascript, and rename your file as html, the browser will understand your file

Comment: problem has been fixed, im not really sure how though. i did follow your answer but it still wasnt working for awhile after that. was an odd problem to begin with as ive never had this problem when starting a new program :s

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling a function inside your script?  If you call a function without brackets, it outputs the script inside the function.

Example:

Let's say we have this code:

```
function printHiThere(name) {
   document.write('Hi there, ' +  name);
}
```

If you invoke this using

```
printHiThere('bob');
```

then the output will be:

```
Hi there, bob
```

But if you invoke it without parameters or brackets, like this:

```
printHiThere
```

Then the output is:

```
function printHiThere(name) {
   document.write('Hi there, ' +  name);
}
```

Could this be your problem?

Comment: the whole point of <script type="text/javascript"> is to execute eveything that follows as javascript. however even the html at the start is shown on the page.

Comment: Ah, then I expect that the problem is a MIME type issue.  Are you showing the page on a server or locally?

If you use DevTools to view the headers, you should see a header that specifies 'text/html' or something similar.  It sounds like it's displaying plain text.

Comment: im doing this on my own laptop at home so its local. and the level of coding im currently doing shouldnt have this kind of issue. the whole point of learning in notepad ++ is its supposed to be easy to use

Comment: That's very odd.  Have you put in a doctype?

Comment: problem has been fixed. im not really sure how though :s it was an odd problem to begin with as its never happened before when starting a new program