# Why Use The <html> Tag?

Tags: html

Everything I have seen says that the HTML code needs it, but mine works fine without it. I'm only using extremely basic HTML without CSS or javascript, if that makes a difference. Could someone please explain?

Comment: html without an html tag puts your browser in quirks mode. Things handle differently there.

Comment: read also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags) and its answers

Comment: browser considers your code as `html` by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything still works because the browser is plugging it in for you. You should use it because it makes your code more clear and standard.

A developer looking at your code might be confused about what they're seeing at first because they would wonder where the `<html>` tag is.

As with any standard, the `<html>` tag guarantees that things will work. Currently the tag *can* be omitted, but I still wouldn't recommend it, to be safe. This is from the W3 spec:

> An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment.
>
> An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment.

Comment: Actually, there is a guarantee. It's in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: @Blender nice investigation! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Everything I have seen says that the HTML code needs it, but mine works fine without it.

That's because you *don't* need it. [The HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) says that you can omit the starting tags (and even the ending tags) of many elements, including `html` and `head`, which makes documents like this actually perfectly valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Text to make me non-empty</title>
<p>Hello world!
```

Browsers will create the `html` and `head` elements even if you don't write out the tags, so omit them if you want. Do note that not all browsers follow the spec properly, so while this behavior would be ideal, some browsers will parse your HTML improperly and force you to be more explicit with your structure.

Comment: You can omit the *tags*. The *elements* are still there.

Comment: @Alohci: My mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the standard.  It helps tell the browser it is `HTML` vs `XML` or some other type of markup and makes it clear what kind of document it is.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp

The browser is just being nice to you and showing what is there without the tag.

Comment: Using w3schools as an authoritative reference isn't the best idea ever, the real W3 is a better choice: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/html.html

Comment: No. The `html` element does *not* differentiate between HTML and XML (or other types of document) - other things do. In particular, the Content-Type is used by web browsers, but the DOCTYPE and XML declarations (if present) and even extension can play a role. A trivial counter example to the incorrect claims of this answer is that XHTML *is* XML and XHTML defines the `html` element.

Answer (score 0):

It is what tells various parties reading the document that it is an HTML document and that this is where it starts.

Comment: With few exceptions (e.g. humans with other context factors), this is incorrect. For instance, the browser *already* knows if it is parsing the resource as XML (XHMTL) or HTML when the element is read. Also, returning a text/plain resource will not result in HTML rendering, even if the text is HTML.