# What should a basic html5 file include?

Tags: html

I was wondering what an html file should ALWAYS include besides `<html>`, `<header>` and `<body>`. I've seen many things, so I'm not sure what to include ALWAYS.

Comment: That’s depends solely on what _you_ need them to contain … maybe google for “HTML5 boilerplate” if you want to see what others are using.

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean by "what I need them to contain"? Like, if its going to have images, web fonts, and such? What about things like normalize.css?

Answer (score 3):

The `html`, `header` and `body` tags are [actually optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642982/941764) in HTML5. The only required element, aside from the doctype definition, is  [`title`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-title-element). So the following would be a completely valid HTML5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>example</title>
```

You can validate that using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the start/end tags of the html/body tags are  optional **IF**:

The <html> start tag is optional unless the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
The <⁄html> end tag is optional unless the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

see [html tag, optional vs. required](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html/html5_html_tag_optional.php)

and the body start/end tags may be omitted **IF** : [see when](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/body/html5_body_tag_syntax.php)