# Can a HTML document be created without the <html> tag?

Tags: html

I found this sample HTML code on gitHub - https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html and noticed that this page has no `<html>` and `</html>`  tags and no `</body>` tag. I was told that these were optional. I understand `<tag />`, but how can one create an html document without the `<html>` tag? What is going on in this example?

The  author tells me that [it is](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/30).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it can be created and it will work in some browsers like Chrome and Firefox without problems but it will break in others. Generally, it's not recommended to do that because, as I already said, it might break functionality in some browsers.

Also, according to the HTML5 specs the html, body and head tags are completely optional. However, it appears that a non-empty `<title>` tag is required in both HTML4 and HTML5.

EDIT: if you are looking for more competent answer you should check this answer:

[Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Comment: So it does not confirm to standards?

Comment: @LordLoh.: Go answer that question yourself, use http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: w3c validator throws an error, but I thought that the JS (and there is come complicated JS there) was adding tags at rendering.

Comment: if you add <!DOCTYPE html> right at the top it will validate

Comment: There already is a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top. The error is `Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.`

Comment: It appears that in order to pass the validation you need at least a title tag like so: <title>awesome title</title>. According to the following page the title tag is a required tag in both HTML4 and HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp

Comment: That works :-)

Conclusion: The sample on github is a hack!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the service. As a rule, I tend to put the `<html>` in any HTML that I'm returning to a client machine. Chrome, for example, will automatically generate the `<html>` tag for you. Others, like IE will not, and will have a difficult time understanding the code.

My recommendation is that you *always* include the `<html>` in your HTML output, because this is the best, cross-browser compliant way of formatting HTML.

**Example**

If you open this file:

```
<h3>Hello World!</h3>
```

In a Chrome browser, and view the elements in the developer console, you will see:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h3>Hello!</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome can handle this, but other browsers can not.

Answer (score 0):

`<html>` and `<body>` tags are a rule in every html page. Some people doesn't use them but you should! In some old browser a page without `<html>` tag could be read in a wrong way.
So put them!

Read here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/qt/html-quick-and-dirty.htm

Answer (score 0):

the start /end tags of a few HTML5 elements can be omitted when specific conditions are met

e.g. The html start tag is optional unless the first thing inside the html element is not a comment
http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html/html5_html_tag_optional.php

but if you don't want to learn these conditions, just don't omit the start/end tags of HTML5 elements, that's the easy way