# What can be validly placed between </body> and </html>, if anything?

Tags: html, semantics, w3c, w3c-validation

I get a lot of requests from clients, all of whom are working with ad agencies and SEO firms, who insist on having all kinds of tags and scripts placed **after** `</body>` and **before** `</html>`. I always thought this was inappropriate, but it is asked for quit often. Some people even become upset and demanding when the code I insert is not explicitly between those two closing tags.

Is this in any way an acceptable HTML practice? If so, why? And what benefit would it even provide?

Comment: Comments and script tags are allowed there, but nothing else there.  Anyone who asks you to put content there is stupid.

Comment: @SLaks most likely they are ignorant, rather than stupid

Comment: @SLaks Is there any benefit to putting a script tag there that is not attainable by placing it immediately before the closing body tag?

Comment: [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html) is pretty clear that no tags are allowed at that position.

Comment: What are clients actually asking for? Are they really asking for code to go there? If so what are they expecting to put there? Or are they simply asking for content to go after the body of the document but before the end in the rendered result?

Comment: ad/seo agencies tend to have IQs trending towards absolute zero. They wouldn't know html if you stapled some of it to the inside of their eyeballs. Ad server code tends to be the absolutely crappiest worst written piles of garbage you've ever seen. They don't care. As long as they get their content in front of eyeballs, they're happy.

Comment: You can also run your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). I did a bare bones example with an empty `<script>` between `</body>` and `</html>` and it invalidated the markup based on that. I agree, however, that the spec is pretty clear about `<html>` only being allowed to have `<head>` and `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

No published HTML specification allows any tags between `</body>` and `</html>`, because the `body` element may only appear as the last child of the `html` element. This is defined by the content model of the `html` element.

What exactly is allowed there depends somewhat on HTML version, but the most permissive version in this respect, HTML5 CR, allows (by the general rules on [Content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models)) “Inter-element whitespace, comment nodes, and processing instruction nodes”.

If you put some elements between `</body>` and `</html>`, browsers actually treat them as appearing at the end of the `body` element. That is, they simply ignore the `</body>` tag. (If you put elements after the  `</html>` tag, browsers similarly interpret them as being in the `body`. So the `</html>` tag has no impact, really.)

Putting anything between `</body>` and `</html>` is normally a pointless risk, since browsers *could* behave differently, and normally nothing should prevent you from putting your elements before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the html or body tags.... Except for [certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags) but you can put comments between them if you like, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing but comments should be placed there and even comments won't have any effect on SEO or page ranking as search engines don't read comments. Script tags should be placed just before the `</body>` as that will make the page load faster, but should not go between `</body>` and `</html>` as that is really bad practice and will probably mess the website up as the browser might render it differently.

I think your clients must be reading instructions incorrectly and you should probably ask them where they got their information from. A lot of sites which ask you to place script tags will *always* say before `</body></html>` and they might be misreading the before text.

If you are ever unsure, then please check http://www.w3.org/ and validate your code through http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: Thank you. Most of the time, these agencies are sending the clients code with instructions. They then forward the instructions to me. They very often insist their code be inserted between these two closing tags. Not before, but literally between. They often become quite upset when they see the code is placed immediately before the closing body tag.

Comment: Just ensure them that that would be bad practice and you are only doing what you feel is correct. Remind them that you are the developer and you know what's right, but be polite as you can be. Maybe even show them the validator from W3C with one page with the tags in between and one where they should be and explain that it becomes invalid. With a little persuasion they might begin to understand your side of it.