# Should I Have Basic Tags Within This Include?

Tags: php, html

Okay, I've got a require (include) for my website's sitemap. Here's an example of a page with the include:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <?php require("site/sitemap.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to my personal work and publishing site. I'm an aspiring game designer, software designer, writer, and filmmaker.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works like a charm, but I'm all about optimization for optimization's sake, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something inefficiently. Before I show you the problem, take a look at my sitemap file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <li>Mainpage</li>
        <li>Discorporation</li>
        <li>SourOath Video Editor</li>
        <li>The Decaying Empire</li>
        <li>Donations</li>
        <li>Archive</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, this works fine, but when I view the source for one of my pages, I get this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <html>
<body>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <li>Mainpage</li>
        <li>Discorporation</li>
        <li>SourOath Video Editor</li>
        <li>The Decaying Empire</li>
        <li>Donations</li>
        <li>Archive</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html> </div>
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to my personal work and publishing site. I'm an aspiring game designer, software designer, writer, and filmmaker.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the include is pasting in the contents of sitemap.php, as expected, with the html and body tags as well. Should my sitemap file contain these basic tags? It seems strange and possibly redundant to have two html's and body's within my site's pages.

Should I only be using these tags once, for my actual page? Or do they not matter at all? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have multiple `<html>` and `<body>` tags. This will confuse the browser, which expects a single set of those tags:

All you need in sitemap.php is this portion:

```
<ul class="sitemap">
    <li>Mainpage</li>
    <li>Discorporation</li>
    <li>SourOath Video Editor</li>
    <li>The Decaying Empire</li>
    <li>Donations</li>
    <li>Archive</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay, but it seems as if html and body tags aren't needed at all? I mean, pages work fine without them.

Comment: Yup, this answer is correct.  You are basically just adding code dynamically.  No need for more tags than what you would expect to see there.

Comment: Oohhhh, so you're not actually including technical code, you're just adding text to the existing code and tags.

Comment: Correct - PHP is simply inserting a chunk of HTML into your existing page, which already has those tags. For a complete discussion of whether those tags are required at all for the main HTML document (an interesting, though separate question), check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags).

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the html and body tag from sitemap.php

```
<ul class="sitemap">
    <li>Mainpage</li>
    <li>Discorporation</li>
    <li>SourOath Video Editor</li>
    <li>The Decaying Empire</li>
    <li>Donations</li>
    <li>Archive</li>
</ul>
```