# creating html document dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<script>
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("Text");
    btn.appendChild(txt);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
</script>
</html>
```

I just started learning HTML and JavaScript.

I was expecting the above code to output a button with a word "text" in it.
Unfortunately, the output was blank. Can someone explain to me why this code didn't work?

Comment: There's no body to attach to

Comment: The javascript is trying to run before the page has loaded causing it to error. You should also have a body tag but that isn't the reason your button isn't being created. This does work without the body tag but i wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: Yeah your right! Theres an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your script won't do anything because it in head so your script run before body you need use window.onload function like this

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("Text");
    btn.appendChild(txt);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this append to the body even if there is no `<body>` to append to?

Comment: Yes, it will append. I have tried this with and without the body tag. Not that i would recommend doing this without the body tag. The issue is the javascript running before the page is read.

Comment: look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags

Comment: @ethylcasin - IMO, a better solution would be to just move the `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>` section.  No `window.onload` assignment will be needed then.  Example shown at the top of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701).

Comment: yes , but she want it in head , whatever it works :)

Answer (score 1):

jsve is close. You need to make sure the code isloaded when the body loads. This is done by calling the body's onload function, like this...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function init(){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("Text");
        btn.appendChild(txt);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that code after the body is loaded:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function addBtn() {
            var btn = document.createElement("button");
            var txt = document.createTextNode("Text");
            btn.appendChild(txt);
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="addBtn()"></body>
</html>
```

A few more comments:

1. You also need to update your `DOCTYPE` to `<!doctype html>` as I show above.
2. Wrap your `<script>` tag inside of a `<head>` tag.
3. No need to capitalize `button`.

Comment: This won't work because the javascript is running before the page is read.  Try `window.onload=function(){*place the javascript here*}`

Comment: @jsve I see it. I have also given another method in the comment.