# Does HTML DOCTYPE inserts an html tag too?

Tags: html, doctype, w3c

We use HTML5 declaration these days `<!DOCTYPE html>` to declare current page as html5 standard.

I found one use through html5boilerplate as it can be useful for specifying language, javascript detection `class="no-js"`. But that doesn't change my mind to omit it, i always forget it anyway.
I want to know if it also automatically inserts an `<html>` tag too.

Like if i wrote in start of my page
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

instead of
`<!DOCTYPE html><html>`

I tried every browser without `<html>`, and everything worked fine, html5 standards were accepted and browsers also added  tag.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing when you omit the `<html>` tag is not relying on the doctype tag to automagically "insert" one after itself, but rather you are relying on the fact that some of the HTML standards did not define it as a requirement (notably HTML5, and HTML1 where it was totally absent).

This means that browsers will just have to cope with the fact that the `<html>` tag might be absent and can not be relied on, and thus don't horribly malfunction if you omit it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags) has more info on the topic: [Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)