# Style sheets and body and head tags in programmatically produced HTML

Tags: html, css, scala, http, functional-programming

I'm using Scala to produce HTTP, HTML and CSS. I also intend to use Scala to produce Javascript but I haven't got to that stage yet.

What are the advantages of using separate style sheets? CSS offers a form of multiple inheritance by which you can organise the styling of your mark up. However Scala already has its own system of multiple inheritance and other functional languages provide their own powerful methods of problem decomposition and declarative composition. While producing separate style sheets, adds algorithmic complexity and hinders the production of comprehensible clean code.

One of the claimed advantages of separate style sheets is that they use less bandwidth. However I find it difficult to believe that CSS uses significant bandwidth compared to images let alone video. So do separate style sheets give advantages to search engine ranks and site classification? Do they speed up or slow down rendering and layout? Do they help accessibility and user defined style? I would have thought not using separate style sheets might actually speed up delivery in HTTP 1.1 if not in 2.0

Similarly with Head and Body nodes /Tags. Do they serve any advantage to justify the added complexity of producing them programmatically? They don't seem to make any functional difference to what the browser produces.

So the question is how important are separate style sheets and Body and Head nodes to producing optimal web sites? Is it OK to put CSS into the HTML leaf Nodes?

Comment: How do you "produce HTTP"?

Comment: @Asad I poll the port, read the socket and then compose the HTTP message header and message body and then write it out to the socket, using java.net.ServerSocket.

Answer (score 0):

The advantages to using separate stylesheets:

- Cachability: no need to re-load the same style over and over again
- Smaller size: even with gzip compression, 400 `div` tags all styled alike will be more bytes on the wire per-page than the page without the styles inlined.
- Possibility: Some CSS *cannot be expressed* in an inline style. For example, any pseudo-element or state selector (`:hover`, `:focus`, etc.)
- DRY: not applicable if you are building a style tree at compile time to apply to an HTML tree at compile time.

The disadvantages:

- Speed: inline styles will be faster to render, since when the browser parses the tag it *knows* what styles apply.
- Locality: inline styles make it easy to see what the element will look like (browser debugging tools make this a moot point)

#### `html` / `head` / `body` - do I need them?

The [general consensus seems to be "yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/135978), principally because you are more likely to run into obscure browser bugs if you *don't* include them (since the "how to choose what to make a child of which element" algorithm isn't blindingly obvious and some of the corner cases aren't necessarily obvious to the developer).