# What's the use of <head> or<html> tag in html?

Tags: html

I just started with web-designing. As mentioned everywhere I was using the above-mentioned tags but even if I did not type those tags in my document gives me the desired outputs. This is working on both html5 and html4.

If this is valid then what's the point of those tags? Semantics?

Comment: fellow this http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but it's so you can specify any optional attributes on those elements.

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king people have raised concerns about w3schools (see http://w3fools.com), it would be better to point them to mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) or w3.org in the future.

Comment: This isn't a terrible question, it's a nice curious observation, but any answers are probably going to be purely opinion based.  The short answer is semantics, and yes, they do themselves have some optional attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly semantics, although you should still consider them required.

As other users have noticed, they do sometimes contain obscure but possibly useful attributes, see [<html>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) [<head>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head).