# What are the drawbacks of ignoring <html> and <body>

Tags: html

Is there any drawback to never using

```
<html> and <body>
```

on your web pages that are written in HTML and PHP?
I mean, everything works perfectly fine with it or without it, so why use it?

Comment: You take the modern firefox and chrome for granted.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags

Answer (score 6):

They are explicitly optional in the spec (so the document will still be valid).

This has been true since the [original spec](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt) (which says *`<!ELEMENT HTML O O  (( HEAD | BODY | %oldstyle)*, PLAINTEXT?)>`*, `O O` meaning Start Tag Optional, End Tag Optional) through to the [current spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) (which says "*An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment. An html element's end tag can be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.*").

They are only mandatory in XHTML since XML has no concept of optional tags.

I've never seen any browser or user-agent fail to handle them correctly in an HTML document. (Note that while the tags are optional, the elements are not, so browsers will insert an HTML, HEAD and BODY elements even if the tags are missing, so any script which tries to find them in the DOM will still work).

The only technical drawback is that you can't put attributes on tags which aren't there, and a `lang` attribute for the HTML element is useful.

Leaving them out can confuse other people who have to maintain your code who don't know that the tags are optional though.

Comment: Every time the topic of optional tags comes up, I think of the whole XHTML debacle, laugh, and finally, cry myself to sleep.

Comment: XHTML seemed like such a nice idea on paper. It was when browsers gave up on the yellow screen of death and just parsed it as tag soup automatically that pushed me over the edge.

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware of that. Firefox still YSODs on invalid XHTML for me. Does Chrome do that?

Comment: huh, I'm getting XML errors in Chrome now. I was sure they'd gotten rid of that. Maybe they put it back in again.

Comment: Someone just called XHTML ["old school"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969671/why-dont-these-nested-table-elements-respect-html-hierarchy#comment61495817_36969671). For reals.

Answer (score 3):

Both `<head>` and `<body>` tags are optional in HTML5. In fact it is recommended by [Google's HTML style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags) to not use them:

```
<!-- Not recommended -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spending money, spending bytes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Sic.</p>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- Recommended -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Saving money, saving bytes</title>
<p>Qed.
```

By not using those tags, some drawbacks include:

- that it is drastically different from what is typically learned for developers, so it may cause some confusion.
- a restriction that a comment cannot be immediately after the `<html>` tag that is omitted.

Reiterating the optional nature of the tags from the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission):

> An **html** element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
>
> A **body** element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a meta, link, script, style, or template element.

See:

- https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `<html>` and `<body>` than your HTML document will be not valid, some libraries/plugins may not work too.

Comment: Valid in HTML 4. Valid in HTML 3.2. Valid in HTML 2. Valid in every version of HTML. Only invalid in XHTML where no tag is optional.

Comment: lord how I wish that wasn't the case.