# Why don't these nested <table> elements respect HTML hierarchy?

Tags: html

[**JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/ydv9jjo0/)

In this SSCCE, there is a `<table>` element nested inside another `<table>` element, but the way they render on the web page is not as expected, and when I checked in the Google Chrome Inspecter/DevTools, I noticed that the two `<table>` elements are appearing to be at the same level of the HTML hierarchy.

**What am I missing here?**

[image]

```css
.outer-table {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.outer-table th {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.inner-table tr {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.inner-table td {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
tfoot td {
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding: 20px;
}
td {}
```

```html
<table class="outer-table">



  <thead class="outer-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>



  <tbody class="outer-table-body">
    <tr>
      <table class="inner-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button class="remove-button">Reset</button>
              <button class="add-button">Save</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </tr>
  </tbody>



</table>
```

Comment: Because your HTML is invalid. You probably forgot a `td` element.

Comment: You miss a <td > in the outer table after the <tr>. Also remember to close it

Comment: You don't need to close it. You just need to open it to start with. (Then again, the OP is using XHTML /> syntax, so it probably makes sense to have an explicit </td> end tag, just to be consistent.)

Comment: I prefer to close it anyway.. Just to be sure;) old school maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nesting tables, I believe you need to place the inner table inside a td tag rather than a tr tag.

Comment: You need both. They are not alternative

Comment: Correct. You don't use a td INSTEAD OF a tr. It's not valid html to put a table inside a tr so you need to add a td.

Comment: Actually.. A table is made of cells. A cell is made of a tr and a td tag. Any content (even just text) must be placed in a cell.

Comment: A table isn't just made of cells - if it were, then there's no reason to have tr. Or tbody/thead/tfoot or colgroup/col. A cell isn't made of a tr and a td. A cell is either a td or a th - that's *inside* a tr (that's inside either a tbody, thead or tfoot). TheEllis is right.