# remove new line before div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code like this

```
<p><span>On this day,<div class="underline-text">Sunday</div>,we, the undersigned:</span></p>
```

**and my css**

```
.underline-text {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
```

But my problem is when i run this code, is show like this :

```
On this day,

    `Sunday,we, the undersigned:`
```

**What i need is like this :**

```
`On this day,Sunday,we, the undersigned:`
```

How i do that way????
NOTE : I'm using bootstrap 3.

UPDATE : Works, i was stupid so i'm changing `<div>` to `<span>`. Thanks you all for the answer.

Why i got -2 vote??? Wat's wrong with my question??? I just asking simple question, and i kno i'm so stupid cause i'm using inline-block on span. But why i got minus for this???

Comment: div is a block element use span instead which is inline.

Comment: Why are you using `display:inline-block;`? This is designed to fill the browser width

Comment: i wanna make div is auto width with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this adjustment:

```
On this day, <span class="underline-text">Sunday</span>,we, the undersigned:
```

A `div` inside a `p` element is invalid HTML. The paragraph element closes before the `div` element begins.

Here's how the browser renders your code:

[image]

For a complete explanation of this behavior see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538733/3597276

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` or `<span>` tags can't contain block-level elements inside them. Most browsers will split it into 2 separate paragraphs. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441670/6424295

Maybe try using a`<div>` instead of a paragraph and get rid of the `<span>` tags, as I don't think they're really doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should be like this:

```css
.underline-text {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
     
     On this day,<span class="underline-text">Sunday</span>,we, the undersigned:
     
</p>
</div>
```