# Simple html with vue.js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

A beginner of vue.js and I followed this link:
https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-vue-js/

Almost copy the code into my html.However it just not working.Can someone help me find what is going wrong?

Here are all the codes:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js">
</script>

<script>

var myModel = {
  name: "Ashley",
  age: 24
};

var myViewModel = new Vue({
  el: '#my_view',
  data: myModel
});

</script>
<div id="my_view">
{{ name }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is just:`{{name}}`

Comment: I am assure that `vue.js` is downloaded successfully .

Comment: This is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/b75yspL8/. What's not working for you?

Comment: @jonmrich why it is not  working in my computer? I just double clicked html file and open  it in chrome.

Comment: Does the jsfiddle work for you?

Comment: @jonmrich Yeah,jsfiddle works. Now the problem solved thanks to the first answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add the `<head>` tag and add the script at the end of the file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my_view">
{{ name }} {{ age }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>

var myModel = {
  name: "Ashley",
  age: 24
};

var myViewModel = new Vue({
  el: '#my_view',
  data: myModel
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is head tag really a must?

Comment: FYI: Here's a post about omitting head tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags

Comment: Thank you sooo much