# my Navigation is not spanning the whole width of the page

Tags: html, css

My Nav bar isn't spanning the whole page (run the snippet code to see). As you can see, there are white borders on the left and right side.  Here is the code:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  background-color: #80DED9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 25;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-20em);
  z-index: -100;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover {
  color: #6d9dc5;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 35.5px 0px;
  margin: -35.5px 40px;
  background-color: #80DED9;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropbtn">Products</li>
        <ul class=dropdown-content>
          <li><a href="cupcakes.html">Cupcakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="bagles.html">Bagles</a>
            <li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="aboutus.html" class="btn">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="contactus.html" class="btn">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Every single thing that pertains to the nav bar is set on `width: 100%`. Please help me understand why the nav bar isn't filling the whole width of the page.

Comment: It seems that you have no `body` tag. But you must have `<body>...</body>`.

Comment: `body` has a default margin. Add `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you so much. This helped a lot.

Comment: @aendeerei — The start and end tags for the body element are optional.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. I knew that browsers render the content "correctly", even if the head and body tags are missing, but I, personally, never really trusted myself to give browsers interpretation tasks.

Comment: @aendeerei — No need for scare quotes. The spec makes the tags optional. There aren't any browsers that fail to correctly implement that part of the spec.

Comment: @Quentin Not according to this answer: [Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags). And to my experience.

Comment: @Quentin ...Oh, and to the accepted answer to this question ;-)

Comment: @aendeerei — IE9 isn't even supported by Microsoft … and that's an obscure bug that depends on a very specific combination of markup.

Comment: @Quentin Ok. Tags are optional, unless one needs at least one of them for a certain purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS below should prevent the white spacing around your Nav bar

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every tag has some default margin and padding at first you have to clear that margin and padding using *{ padding:0px; margin:0px} that * select all the element and set margin and padding 0.

```css
*{    
   margin: 0px;
   padding:0px;

}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  background-color: #80DED9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 25;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-20em);
  z-index: -100;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover {
  color: #6d9dc5;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 35.5px 0px;
  margin: -35.5px 40px;
  background-color: #80DED9;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn">Products</li>
      <ul class=dropdown-content>
        <li><a href="cupcakes.html">Cupcakes</a></li>
        <li><a href="cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
        <li><a href="bagles.html">Bagles</a>
          <li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li class="buttons"><a href="aboutus.html" class="btn">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="buttons"><a href="contactus.html" class="btn">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is set your CSS like this:

```
body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100vw;} 
nav{width: 100vw;}
```

Using the 100vw will set the item's to be 100% of the viewable width.  This should eliminate your problem.