# Use of HTML tag

Tags: html, web

Recently I created a demo webpage using HTML which contains an unordered list.
My code is:

```
<Html>
<Head>
    <Title>Demo</Title>
</Head>
<Body>
    <Ul>
        <Li>one
        <Li>two
        <Li>three
    </Ul>
</Body>
</Html>
```

But if I do only this:

```
<Ul>
    <Li>one
    <Li>two
    <Li>three
</Ul>
```

and save it with a *.html* extension then both gives the same result. So what is the use of `<html>` tag?

Comment: nice explaination about the tags and browser [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag tells the browser that the document is HTML. The reason that works without it, is because your browser is smart enough to see you have HTML there and fill in with the missing tags.

But sometimes if you have a more complicated document it may not know how to fill the blanks and other browsers may not have that functionality. So, always use the `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The html tag will tell browsers it is going to be html and not xml.

However your browser will interpret it as html anyways, so even the Google style guide for HTML will tell you to Omit it.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag tells the browser that this is an HTML document. The  tag represents the root of an HTML document. The  tag is the container for all other HTML elements (except for the  tag).
It is necessary for you to write  or  , as it acknowledges the browser of the scripting language or else complex codes on older browsers can not be interpreted. 
I have been working in Html from past 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

this is a template for HTML. In head tags we set char set which is important as well as a Title for web page. Also, inside head there can be written other useful tags or can be linked bootstrap. This is a template you have to create when you start an HTML document. Your code fine without HTML structure but when your code will grow is size and get more complicated you will have errors in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your Browser automatically add

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
............
    </body>
</html>
```

That's why You don't see the difference.

If you check this   **Right Click on browser->Click Inspect**
Then you will see that