# What is the use of the <body> tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I just started learning HTML and learned that elements such as `<p>` and `<h1>` need to be placed in the `<body>` element. Even without a `<body>` element, these tags still work. Does `<body>` serve any meaningful use by keeping these elements grouped? In other words, which use cases does `<body>` have by acting as a container for contents?

Comment: See the excellent answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

> The HTML `<body>` tag defines the main content of the HTML document or the section of the HTML document that will be directly visible on your web page. This tag is also commonly referred to as the  element.

Source: https://www.techonthenet.com/html/elements/body_tag.php

Essentially this will be the part of your HTML which the user will see. Everything in the `<head>` section is for metadata and browser instructions.