# Can I use Django template language directly at top level of a HTML file i.e. without <HTML> or <body> tags ? Example -

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

```
  .
  .
  . (HTML code)
```

{% else %}

```
  .
  .
  . (HTML code)
```

{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this post answers your question:
[Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

The (HTML) and (Body) tags can be omitted and therefore your django template code should work as you expect. Curious though, why would you not include (html) at the top anyway?

Comment: The post you linked here, states that you don't need those for writing HTML code, but that post not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Then what to do if I want to implement the functionality where i want to check a condition first and then if the condition is true then I want to extend?

Comment: No, there ins't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, in fact, you will find many situations where is practical to break down your templates in several reusable parts, that you can later user with the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#incude) tag. And such template fragments could not have any HTML tag at all.

Comment: No, you can't. {% extends %}  must be always the very first tag in your templates.

Comment: Then what to do if I want to implement the functionality where i want to check a condition first and then if the condition is true then I want to extend?

Comment: Check the condition in a view, and renders the template you want according. Write two templates one for each case.

Comment: I already knew that. All I wanted to confirm is that 'Is there no way to do what I want using a single template?' .