# How <style> tag is working inside <body> tag?

Tags: html, css

I used `<style>` tag inside `<body>` tag and `<h1>` tag inside `<head>` tag. And it worked. How is it working perfectly?

[image]

Comment: If you use your browsers debug tools to inspect your page, you will probably find that the h1 has been moved from the head to the body. Browsers will often attempt to fix mistakes if they can.

Comment: Browsers are smart enough to figure out what you meant in many scenarios.

Comment: first duplicate to explain the issue related to your h1 inside head and second one to explain the style (considering reading all the answer as there is new information in bottom answers)

Comment: another related one to get more tricks about HTML structure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/8620333 .. you will get surprised about what you can write and what you will obtain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `style` contains style information for a document, or part of a document.  so no matter where you have the `h1` (in this case), although you shouldn't have inside `head` because it is invalid HTML , it will be styled. check more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)

> The `<style>` element can be included inside the `<head>` or `<body>` of the
>   document, and the styles will still be applied, however it is
>   recommended that you include your styles in the `<head>` for
>   organizational purposes — it is a lot better to separate your content
>   from your presentation as much as possible. Even better, put your
>   styles in external stylesheets and apply them using `<link>` elements.

Comment: "no matter where you have the `h1` in this case, it will be styled." This is half true. It's true that the style will apply to the `<h1>` no matter where it is, but it's not true that the `<h1>` can be anywhere. Some very specific things happen when the browser finds an `<h1>` where it shouldn't be, like inside `<head>`, and styles only apply after those things happen.

Comment: I didn't say it could be anywhere, I said, `no  matter where you have`, so if it is in the `head` (which shouldn't of course), it will be styled anyway

Comment: @JordanRunning I've updated the answer to be more concise

Comment: That’s the part you’re missing. “If it is in the `head`” is not a scenario that ever applies. Regardless of what you write in your HTML, the browser never puts an `h1` element inside the `head` element.

Comment: @JordanRunning  now its covered :) thanks!

Answer (score -5):

**Add Stylesheet in the body:**

```
body{
      backhround:#000;
      color:#fff;
     }
```