# XHTML element "meta" not allowed as child

Tags: html, spring, netbeans, xhtml

Hello i tried to use netbeans and tried to learn Springboot in netbeans .

I got an error evethough i followed the tutorial even when i'm just copy pasting from the website, and it gave me red exclamation in index.html file in the 3rd line with message saying "xhtml element meta not allowed as child of html element meta in this context"

this is the website : [THIS TUTORIAL](http://%20https://omeragca.wordpress.com/2019/04/30/spring-boot-jsf-primefaces-demo/)

here's the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=flight.xhtml" />
</html>
```

here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.20</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.20</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
         <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
         <version>7.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.SP1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <version>1.18.10</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

this is my flight.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: `meta` needs to be in a `head` for **XHTML**, as ***XHTML is not HTML***. It will work in HTML without an explicit head element.. so read XHTML tutorials / resources for writing XHTML.

Comment: Or, maybe switch to HTML? It is 2020.. and Java-XML-everything been dead to me for years >_<

Comment: the error i got is in the index.html file not my flight.xhtml :(

Comment: That error would not be caused by HTML in a modern browser. The _editor_ might not understand valid HTML5; or maybe the _editor_ is treating it as XHTML regardless. What does a _browser_ show? Or, just place it inside an explicit `head` element and move on..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/2864740 — “A head element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the head element is an element [like `title` or `meta`].”