# Rails rendering navbar inside body tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering a navbar in application.html.erb like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%= render "shared/head" %>
    <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/alerts' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, in my browsers inspector I see the navbar being rendered inside the body tag.

[image]

Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually omit tags like `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`, see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094615/9595653

Since you're not rendering your navbar inside the header (why would you), the browser sees your navbar as the beginning of the body tag and renders it as such.