# Can you leave out closing tags in HTML for tags that extend throughout the document?

Tags: html, markup

I was wondering about a concept with HTML: closing tags. I want to save space to make it more web-friendly. I thought about this while writing a web page for a web design class, and there is a similar question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags/5642982).

Here is an example that sets the text color to red and the background to yellow:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffff00">
<font color="#ff0000">
...
```

It is commonly used with `br` and `img` tags. I was thinking about leaving closing tags out for tags that are used throughout the page or at least throughout after the tag is used.

*Is this compatible with all modern browsers? And furthermore, do most web developers accept this practice?*

Comment: If you want to save space, there are many other ways to accomplish that than manually adjusting your HTML. [You should write valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) so your pages look consistent across browsers instead of relying on browsers to guess correctly what your HTML meant (e.g. SEO, accessibility, etc). If you're only looking to simplify your HTML, there are many [templating engines available](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+template+engine) (along with many of server-side frameworks) that would provide a more reliable result.

Comment: I am wondering if search engines would encourage this as well, or at least appreciate it. The link above seems to suggest that they would on a related topic. Search engines work with huge amounts of data and something like this might speed it up.

Comment: [Search engine crawlers don't _need_ valid HTML, but it certainly makes the data more clear to them.](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-valid-html/258881/) Writing "shorter" HTML for the purposes of making the files easier to edit isn't the right approach. You should try to output complete and valid HTML, and use a separate tool to help you edit the files more easily instead of making the output worse.

Answer (score 2):

You should *ALWAYS* close your tags.  Most browsers are "forgiving" ... but that doesn't make it "right".

You should also use CSS (rather than HTML tag attributes) whenever possible.

POOR:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffff00">
<font color="#ff0000">
...
```

BETTER:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffff00">
<font color="#ff0000" />
...  <!-- Note: your HTML should eventually have a closing "</body>" -->
```

MUCH BETTER:

```
<style>
  body {background-color: "#ffff00";}
  ...
```

PS:

Q: What's "compatible"?

A: MDN WebDocs is a great resource:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Structures/Compatibility_tables

Comment: You're mistaken.  You *should* close your tags, and most browsers *do* "understand".  As WOUNDEDStevenJones said, you should *always* write valid HTML.  Unfortunately, there are always exceptions.  Q: Is there any particular browser you need to support that you're having trouble with?  Q: Are you familiar with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Structures/Compatibility_tables?