# Why we need <HTML> tag in html?

Tags: html

I searched before but I couldn't get a logical answer.
I want to know what's the use of < HTML > tag in HTML?
Why do we use this tag and how is this useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Comment: document type defines by <!DOCTYPE> in html5 , i think we declare document type by this way and not by HTML tag

Comment: @AradOlfati — No. The Doctype (which is not a tag) just triggers the switch from Quirks Mode to Standards Mode. The `Content-Type` HTTP header tells the browser it is an HTML document.

Comment: @maksymiuk — No, see my comment to AradOlfati

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Look at [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element). It says:

> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
>
> An html element's end tag can be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

That said, if you don't have it, you can't put a `lang` attribute that applies to the whole document on it.

Comment: Do you mean the whole usage of Html tag is just for lang attribute?

Comment: No, that's just the most useful (IMO) thing you can do with it.