# What is CDATA in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, cdata

What is the use of CDATA inside JavaScript tags and HTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// <![CDATA[

// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.

But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.

**CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data**

> The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.
>
> Characters like "<" and "&" are illegal in XML elements.
>
> "<" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.
>
> "&" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.
>
> Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of "<" or "&" characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.
>
> Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.
>
> A CDATA section starts with "`<![CDATA[`" and ends with "`]]>`"

**Use of CDATA in program output**

> CDATA sections in XHTML documents are liable to be parsed differently by web browsers if they render the document as HTML, since HTML parsers do not recognise the CDATA start and end markers, nor do they recognise HTML entity references such as `&lt;` within `<script>` tags. This can cause rendering problems in web browsers and can lead to cross-site scripting vulnerabilities if used to display data from untrusted sources, since the two kinds of parsers will disagree on where the CDATA section ends.

[A brief SGML tutorial](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.1.5).

Also, see the [Wikipedia entry on CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

Comment: I think I have a better question then. 
In broad strokes, what benefits are associated with using the CDATA tag?

Comment: @ajameswolf you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Answer (score 100):

`CDATA` has no meaning at all in HTML.

`CDATA` is an XML construct which sets a tag's contents that is normally #PCDATA - parsed character data, to be instead taken as #CDATA, that is, non-parsed character data. It is only relevant and valid in XHTML.

It is used in `script` tags to avoid parsing `<` and `&`. In HTML, this is not needed, because in HTML, `script` is already #CDATA.

Comment: so, y does people use it inside Javascript tags? where does it has any meaning and what for, thanks

Comment: @SexyMF Probably because these people type XHTML documents instead of SGML/HTML, and/or they want to help less standards compliant browsers to correctly load their pages regardless.

Comment: Even though it's almost 6 years old, this is still the best explanation of `CDATA` I've seen.

Comment: It does has meaning in HTML, depends on whether you encounter the issue

Answer (score 21):

CDATA is **Obsolete**.

*Note that CDATA sections should not be used within HTML; they only work in XML.*

So do not use it in HTML 5.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection#Specifications

[image: Screenshot from MDN]

Comment: I am confused about what is changing.  1) Character Data still exists in DOM4?  https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-characterdata   2)  Yet the the CDATASection is being removed?  https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-core  What will be the alternative?  Mandatory encoding or all `<` and `&` and placed in some other tag?  How about supporting old documents?  Are the browsers suddenly going to drop CDATA support?  So we can't process documents created by others over which we have no control?  Or just resort to manual string fiddling?

Comment: Just escape the special characters.

Comment: For creation of XML, I understand, simply escape characters.  However, my concern is how to process CDATA sections (e.g. from feeds we can't control and may be slow to update their format), after the browsers drop CDATASection from the DOM?  When will they drop?  FF 49 is still showing me CDATASection in the DOM.  It isn't clear to me how to handle in this case during the transitional time after it has been obsoleted and removed from browser.  Will just be seen as a text node?  An error (bad tag)?  Just trying to avoid ugliness of manually finding markers in text to pull out the data inside.

Comment: CDATA as such is not deprecated. XHTML is based on XML, so it must support CDATA. (In HTML, the CDATA markup has no meaning; it will be just parsed as a bogus comment.)

It is the CDATASection interface that is deprecated; if a page is parsed as XHTML, its contents will appear in the DOM as a normal text node.

Comment: Sorry XHTML is out! But if you want a HTML/XML you can use XHTML5. FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#XHTML5_(XML-serialized_HTML5)

Comment: Ironically the mozilla link no longer says anything about it being deprecated and shows that all current browsers support it.

Comment: @CTS_AE you right, the word they use is: Obsolete !

Answer (score 19):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA:

> Since it is useful to be able to use less-than signs (<) and
>   ampersands (&) in web page scripts, and to a lesser extent styles,
>   without having to remember to escape them, it is common to use CDATA
>   markers around the text of inline  and  elements in
>   XHTML documents. But so that the document can also be parsed by HTML
>   parsers, which do not recognise the CDATA markers, the CDATA markers
>   are usually commented-out, as in this JavaScript example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write("<");
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Man... I used to see this all the time when I started learning JavaScript... really takes me back.

Answer (score 13):

**A way to write a common subset of HTML and XHTML**

In the hope of greater portability.

In HTML, `<script>` is magic escapes everything until `</script>` appears.

So you can write:

```
<script>x = '<br/>';
```

and `<br/>` won't be considered a tag.

This is why strings such as:

```
x = '</scripts>'
```

must be escaped like:

```
x = '</scri' + 'pts>'
```

See: [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

But XML (and thus XHTML, which is a "subset" of XML, [unlike HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml)), doesn't have that magic: `<br/>` would be seen as a tag.

`<![CDATA[` is the XHTML way to say:

> don't parse any tags until the next `]]>`, consider it all a string

The `//` is added to make the CDATA work well in HTML as well.

In HTML `<![CDATA[` is not magic, so it would be run by JavaScript. So `//` is used to comment it out.

The XHTML also sees the `//`, but will observe it as an empty comment line which is not a problem:

```
//
```

That said:

- compliant browsers should recognize if the document is HTML or XHTML from the initial doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` vs `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`
- compliant websites could rely on compliant browsers, and coordinate doctype with a single valid `script` syntax

But that violates the golden rule of the Internet:

> don't trust third parties, or your product will break

Comment: "In HTML, <script> is magic escapes everything until </script> appears." actually per spec it would be until "</script(\w)+" appears

Answer (score 6):

CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities. User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:

- Replace character entities with characters,
- Ignore line feeds,
- Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.