# How disable date selection for previous days in RichFaces Calendar?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, calendar, richfaces

I would to disable the dates before the current date in `<rich:calendar>`.
I already Googled about it, but none seems to work so far.

Any idea how to do this in a easy way ?

This is my code so far:

```
<rich:calendar id="since" popup="false" value="#{c.since}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" firstWeekDay="1" showWeeksBar="false" showApplyButton="false" showFooter="false"  >
    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="_since"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

Comment: I think you should roll your own control mechanism via backing bean.

Comment: I will do that, but I would like to have this feature in the view too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown in the [Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=clientStylingDisablement):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var curDt = new Date();
    disableBeforeToday = function(day) {
        return (curDt.getTime() - day.date.getTime() < 0);
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
…

<rich:calendar dayDisableFunction="disableBeforeToday" …>
```

<del>Note that you have to use `&lt;` because the JSF engine will think `<` is the beginning of a new tag.</del>

Comment: You can use CDATA section around javascripts to avoid the mess with `&...;` escaping in code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html

Comment: I didn't saw this showcase, it's not the same as the current showcase. Thank you for your answer and sorry if I bother you with something that already was explained in the showcase.

Comment: It's not the same but disabling the days before today is part of the showcased code. And you're not bothering, I'm linking to showcase more to show where I got it from than to show you you were not looking hard enough ;)