# Set div height to window.innerHeight in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I wanted to set the div height of element to innerHeight of the browser. I dont want css or jQuery to take place here. It has to change its height dynamically with window resize. So i made this script and its not working as i thought.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload=
window.onresize=function(){
    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    left.style.height = 'height +('px')';    
}
```

Can someone correct my code and make it work. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bPsFV/)

You can add `height:500px;` to the left element. and see what i want. But i need to fit the browser height.

**SOLVED**

```
//<![CDATA[ 
            function resize()
            {
                var heights = window.innerHeight;
                document.getElementById("left").style.height = heights -50 + "px";
            }
            resize();
            window.onresize = function() {
                resize();
            };
            //]]>
```

Thanks to Thirumalai murugan's answer.

Comment: Are you getting any error in firebug console?

Comment: no i dint get any error

Comment: why would you need this? just add height: 100% to your 'left' css :)

Comment: I can't use height:100%. here because i have a another div with height:100% inside this div and made it overflow:scroll. so i need javascript to make this work as i thought.

Comment: Can u create a fiddle for this

Comment: ok i will create and edit my question

Comment: take a look at jsfiddle

Comment: `height: 100vw;` will make your div the height of the window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem I have found is `window.load` may fired before DOM element created, you can remove `html,body` css but that will give some margin to `html,body`, that should be handle in javascript if you don't want to use the css, `#left` css rule is used only to understand the div height

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Thirumalai-Window size</title>
        <style type="text/css">
           #left{width:200px;background:red;}
           #inner{height:100%;overflow-y:scroll;}      
           html,body{margin: 0px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
            function resize()
            {
                var heights = window.innerHeight;
                document.getElementById("left").style.height = heights + "px";
            }
            resize();
            window.onresize = function() {
                resize();
            };
            //]]>  

        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

### update

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bPsFV/1/)

Comment: you code works but it has some problem. it exceeds innerHeight a little

Comment: @Kishore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html see this post will give your enough answer its basically text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser (help full for non javascript browser not to parse this text)

Comment: I want to place this side bar between two div. How to do that?

Comment: @Vinoth please check http://jsfiddle.net/thirumalaimurugan/bPsFV/245/ is it your expectation?

Answer (score 19):

it can be done with CSS3:

just set div heigth using Viewport-Percentage Lengths

```
div {
    height:100vh;
}
```

[similar question and detailed info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Comment: Be advised there are potential pitfalls with this approach in mobile devices. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    left.style.height = height + "px";
}
```

You had an error in last line of the function, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the 100% height for my google map container with:

```
document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].offsetHeight + "px";
```

[more details here](https://www.timewasters-place.com/div-layer-with-100-height-the-javascript-way/comment-page-1/#comment-449378)