# button that would load an external html as a layover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a button that once clicked,
an overlay window would open up, containing HTML from an external file.

I've tried to combine [this code](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) [with the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694693/how-to-have-jqueryui-dialog-box-dynamically-load-content)
but something is wrong I guess:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
      $( ".selector" ).dialog({
          open: function(event, ui) {
              $('#divInDialog').load('popup.html', function() {
                  alert('Load was performed.');
              });
          }
      });

      $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
          $( "#selector" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  </script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="selector"/>
<div id="divInDialog"></div></div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first, `<div class="selector"/>` should be `<div class="selector">`.

Comment: `$( "#selector" ).dialog( "open" );` should be `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "open" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aQFnA/))

**HTML:** you have used `<div class="selector"/>`

```
<div class="selector">
    <div id="divInDialog"></div>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
        'autoOpen':false,
        open: function(event, ui) {
        $('#divInDialog').load('popup.html', function() {
           alert('Load was performed.');
         });
       }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( ".selector" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

You need to use `'autoOpen':false` to stop automatic popup load at initialization. Also, you have used `$( "#selector" ).dialog( "open" );` but it should be `.` instead of `#` because `#` means `id` while `.` means a class and you have `<div class="selector">`.

Also, always put your `jQuery` code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //... })` so those code will run when `DOM` is ready, here I've used a shortcut but no problem.

Comment: Good catch on the selectors. However I don't think this will work because the anonymous function executes as soon as it loads but the elements are not on the page yet.

Comment: thanks, both answers seem to work, so I can't tell the difference

Comment: @jayjay, Read my answer, everything I've explained and `$(function(){   })` is just a shortcut of `$(document).ready(function(){   })`.

Comment: @jayjay, Also you have invalid `HTML`, I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @SheikhHeera maybe I'm wrong but jsfiddle wraps your js in a load handler if you specify 'onload' in the options. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203922/jsfiddle-wrap-in-onload. And $(function() { etc is not a shortcut for $(document).ready(function() { etc

Comment: @mcbex, You should check my fiddle and remove the `$(...)` and then see what happens.

Comment: @mcbex, It's ok, no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'opener' and 'selector' elements aren't in the DOM yet when you try to reference them. Try wrapping all your js in the callback to the documents ready event: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('#divInDialog').load('popup.html', function() {
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( ".selector" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Comment: that seems to work, thanks, but why does the popup show as soon as i open the page, rather than only when i click the button?

Comment: set autoOpen to false on the dialog: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen (it is true by default)

Comment: I edited the code to add the autoOpen: false example