# In JSFiddle, why is this global variable not defined on `window`?

Tags: javascript, scope, jsfiddle

I have [this code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uj4yew4/):

```
var a = 1;  

function b() {  
    var a = 10;  
    alert(window.a);  
}  

b();
```

Why is `a` is undefined here? It's already defined in global namespace, i.e., `window`. (See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uj4yew4/) for an example of this unexpected behavior.)

Comment: I mean if i write 1st statement without var then a = 1 but with var a = undefined.

Comment: I tried it and it alerted `1`.

Comment: works for me as well

Comment: Is this whole code running inside another scope?  Perhaps a jsfiddle with its default (wrap in onload) settings? For example: [default settings](http://jsfiddle.net/syvbnqdw/), and [changed to nowrap, place in head](http://jsfiddle.net/syvbnqdw/1/) (this one works as expected).

Comment: Its works for me on chrome and ie11 with an alert of `1`. Did you use another browser? Was the code encapsulate in other bracket?

Comment: If you remove the window and just call it alert(a); it works on all the browsers. There is a problem that you assign the global variable inside inner scope and try to call the global variable in a scope that has 2 - "a" parameters ;]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running this code in a fiddle that does not have the location set to "No wrap", or any circumstance in which you're not at the top-level scope, your outer `a` is **not** the global variable `window.a`. Consider a simple example where your code is wrapped inside a function called `wrappingFunc`:

```
// THIS would be the global `a`, outside `wrappingFunc`
var a = "now the global a is defined";

function wrappingFunc() {
    // this is NOT the global `a`
    var a = 1;  

    function b() {  
        var a = 10;  
        alert(window.a);  
    }  

    b();  
}

wrappingFunc();
```

This is exactly what JSFiddle does when you set the location to `onLoad` or `onDomready`. (See [What is the difference between onLoad, onDomready, No wrap - in <head>, and No wrap - in <body>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985800/what-is-the-difference-between-onload-ondomready-no-wrap-in-head-and-no-w)) My `wrappingFunc` example is in actuality an `onload` or `ondomready` listener function, which prevents the keep from running in a global context.

Comment: Yes, I was running this code on  jsfiddle. I was not aware that  jsfiddle is wrapping the code.