# JS: local var X global (window) var

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Studying global vars in JS [here](https://javascript.info/global-object), I set out to try it and to my surprise this:

```js
var thisVar = "global var";

function showVarLet() {
  var thisVar = "local var";
  console.log("%s   %s", thisVar, window.thisVar);
}
showVarLet();
```

gives me:

```
local var
undefined
```

but the same in the browser console, gives me:

```
local var
global var
```

So, what´s with this window object?

EDIT:

I tried to check in the console what would happen if instead of `window.thisVar` I referenced `this.thisVar`, my assumption was that I would access the local variable but I keep accessing the global one, why so?

Comment: *"gives me:

`local var
undefined`"* Where?

Comment: In the snippet getting the correct output

Comment: well, in which runtime you execute above where you said `gives me`

Comment: You have probably run it on a site like jsfiddle or plunker. It will give you `undefined` because they usually wrap the code in the `javascript` section in a function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080320/in-jsfiddle-why-is-this-global-variable-not-defined-on-window

Comment: I just wrote an html file, put the code inside `<script>`, created a button like this `<button type="button" onclick="global()">Global</button>` and the code I showed is in a function called `global()` inside my `<script>` tag. Then I just open this html in Chrome or Firefox and click on the button.

Comment: `var` is scoped to the nearest function. If you use it inside a function called `global`, it won't become global. A variable is a global variable if it's declared outside of any function. Which is what happens when you run it in the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.variableName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148997/window-variablename) and [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431)

Comment: @adiga, I´m posting a (apparent) issue I´m having, the one you posted is more general and wants to know the concept.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148997/window-variablename is not a duplicate of mine. Moderators don´t read and downvote :/

Comment: What do you mean "*the one you posted is more general and wants to know the concept*"? The concepts are exactly what you need to learn here. `window.variableName ` duplicate has many useful explainers on *when* a variable gets attached to the window object. The other has multiple examples on scope of the `var` and global variables. Thoroughly go through them and then explain why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @adina, none of the answers given there apply to my example. Jonas Wilms below probably figured out the issue I was having. The "possible duplicates" you posted are questions around the concept of global variables. You just found random stuff regarding global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the code I showed is in a function called `global()`

then none of the two `thisVar`s is global, one is a local variable of the `global()` function, the other one is a local variable of `showVarLet()`. You cannot access local variables via `window.`.

Comment: I guess your answer must be right. I´m guessing that I have nested functions then. Do you know how I access  variables from one level up?

Comment: no, cause it is impossible