# Datatables YADCF error reseting all column (exResetAllFilters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, yadcf

I'm using  [YADCF](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) plugin for [datatables](http://datatables.net/) and I'm using exResetAllFilters to reset all column filters but it doesn't work.

I have done an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ad23/q1sy3yo2/3/) using Jsfiddle.
Using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firebug/) I can see the error:

> TypeError: string is undefined

```
return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
```

I have changed this function in the YADCF library and also generateTableSelectorJQFriendly to check if string is empty.

```
function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
    if (string) {
        return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }
    else {
        return string;
    }
}

function generateTableSelectorJQFriendly(tmpStr) {
    if (tmpStr) {
        tmpStr = replaceAll(tmpStr, ".", "-");
        tmpStr = replaceAll(tmpStr, ' ', '');
        return tmpStr.replace(":", "-").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("#", "-");
    }
    else {
        return tmpStr
    }
}
```

After these changes I see a different error

> TypeError: table_arg.fnDraw is not a function

```
table_arg.fnDraw(settingsDt);
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in jsfiddle was just a jsfiddle issue related to its [wrapping way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985800/what-is-the-difference-between-onload-ondomready-no-wrap-in-head-and-no-w),

I have solved it by using `.click` instead of *dom onclick* (I did so only because its jsfiddle - in a normal web app you can use onclick without any problems) , [see working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1sy3yo2/10/), if you have any other issue that can be reproduced feel free to ask