# HTML is displayed as raw

Tags: android, html

I am using following code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View innerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_image_list, null);

TextView tv = (TextView)  innerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sorting);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sort_by_num_messages)));
```

The String sort_by_num_messages is defined as

```
<string name="sort_by_likes"><![CDATA[Sort by <b>Messages</b>]]></string>
```

The problem is that it is displayed as follows:
Sort by < b >Messages< / b >

The code was working in an other activity there I was not using the LayoutInflator.
The code is used in a SherlockFragment used as Tab.

Comment: Everything in `cdata` would be ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid off the CDATA stuff and just quote the string like so:

```
<string name="sort_by_likes">"Sort by <b>Messages</b>"</string>
```

Comment: I have now really strange behavior. I moved the code to a handler method. Now if I do it without CDATA it desplays "Sort by Messages" without bold. If I add again CDATA, I have the "Sort by Messages" with Messages bold. Can you explain this?

Comment: Is the line `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sort_by_num_messages)));` still the same? Then I cannot explain that behavior. Sorry.

Comment: It is still the Same.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what your code should display.
Anything inside `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` should not be parsed and should show up exactly as you write it.

You can read more here:
[What is CDATA in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html/7092279#7092279)

Comment: wow. I wonder why it is working in my other activity? I use it the same way, simply without the inflator