# Should I include <![CDATA[""]]> when validating HTML document with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am new to JavaScript and want to know whether I should include the CDATA tag in the JavaScript place when I am validating HTML document (which has the JavaScript).
And can I know if there is a way to validate JavaScript?

Thank you so much!

Comment: thank you. And is there a way I can validate JavaScript?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to validate?  HTML and JavaScript are usually not validated themselves... *input* given in HTML elements may need to be validated, but it's difficult to know if that's what you're trying to do without an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [What is CDATA in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html)

So if you intend to parse the HTML document as an XML document, you'll need to add the CDATA.

---

You can validate JavaScript with lint tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), most IDEs will have some form of integration for these tools.