# Code in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display this code, in my website:

```
<title>MY_TITLE</title>
```

I tried to use the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags without success. Its wrote that I can't use title tags on those tags.

Again, I want to display this code (This code shouldn't do nothing). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display and show HTML code on a web page so that it is not executed, you need to convert the `<` and `>` into it's [ascii](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) equivalent of `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Try following

```
&lt;title&gt;MY_TITLE&lt;/title&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<title> MY_TITLE </ tit`le>
This code has to go inside label "`<![CDATA[ "-->code here<--" ]]>`"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092306/4504069