# Is any of the following CDATA indicative of a security issue?

Tags: wordpress, security, cdata

Looking through the source of an Wordpress site Im working on, I see a few lines of CDATA in various places. 2 examples:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var userSettings = {"url":"\/","uid":"14","time":"1472656583","secure":"1"};
var userSettings = {"url":"\/","uid":"14","time":"1472656583","secure":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var commonL10n = {"warnDelete":"You are about to permanently delete these items.\n  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete.","dismiss":"Dismiss this notice."};
var commonL10n = {"warnDelete":"You are about to permanently delete these items.\n  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete.","dismiss":"Dismiss this notice."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is CDATA in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html)

Comment: @milankyada I'm not asking what CDATA is