# Use and Deletion of CDATA tag in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What is CDATA tag in masterpages and page layouts of sharepoint 2013? Does deleting CDATA tag from the HTML have any effect on the page? Also, can we delete comments generated by sharepoint ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is CDATA in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html)

Comment: Thank you, it answers part of my question. But, i want it specific to sharepoint whether deleting it and other comments have any affect on the functionality of the site.