# Is there a Python function that encodes output for JavaScript contexts?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-3.6

In Python 3.6+, is there a succinct way to [encode output for JavaScript contexts](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-for-javascript-contexts)?

This means, if I start with any unsanitized input string, encode it properly, then replace `VALUE` below with it, all XSS attacks in the webpage will be prevented. The input won't be able to break out of the JavaScript string, nor the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var a = 'VALUE';
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

The link I provided above is the official [OWASP cheatsheet for XSS prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-for-javascript-contexts), which states that all non-alphanumeric characters must be hex escaped. They provide a Java implementation in the article, but I have not been able to find a Python implementation except [this one](https://github.com/alberanid/owasp-esapi-python/blob/master/esapi/reference/default_encoder.py#L169) which has not been updated since 2010. So I wrote my own:

```py
import curses.ascii

def as_js_in_html(value):
    result = ''
    for char in value:
        if curses.ascii.isalnum(char):
            result += char
        else:
            char_hex = format(ord(char), 'x')
            if len(char_hex) <= 2:
                result += '\\x' + char_hex.rjust(2, '0')
            elif len(char_hex) <= 4:
                result += '\\u' + char_hex.rjust(4, '0')
            else:
                result += '\\U' + char_hex.rjust(8, '0')
    return result
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `json.dumps(value)` should do what you want.

Comment: `json.dumps(value)` is awesome! Unfortunately I can still break out of the HTML though. `json.dumps("</script><script>alert('XSS');</script>")` returns the same string, which breaks out of the HTML successfully, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_white3/o7mrb6xw/) which displays an "XSS" alert.

Comment: I always wondered why PHP's `json_encode()` escapes forward slashes. I guess that explains it (`<\/script>` won't break out). Unfortunately, it doesn't look like `json.dumps()` has a similar option.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a [CDATA Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection), which is valid in XML. A CDATA section is declared using `<![CDATA[`, continues until `]]>`, and protects the input from breaking out of the HTML. This can simplify the code you have to write yourself. Here, `VALUE` is an XSS attack, which doesn't work because the input is within CDATA, so it can't break out of the HTML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script>
  // <![CDATA[
    var a = "</script><script>alert('XSS');</script>";
    console.log(a);
  // ]]>
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

As explained on the MDN docs:

"When inside a CDATA section, the symbols `<` and `&` don't need escaping as they normally do" ([see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection)). This means we don't have to HTML escape the input anymore.

"[A CDATA Section] will only work with XML, not HTML documents (as HTML documents do not support CDATA sections)" ([see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createCDATASection#notes)).

XML documents must be served using `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` ([see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/XHTML#xhtml_document)). Otherwise, "browsers parse those documents using HTML parsers rather than XML parsers."

**Caveats:**

1. You must serve the XML HTML document with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`, or this won't work.
2. You need to use something like [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to prevent newlines and quotation marks from escaping out of the JavaScript variable.
3. Any CDATA closing sequence, `]]>`, must be removed from the unsanitized input or replaced.
4. CDATA sections were [previously made obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html) in the standard, then [added back due to web breakage](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/pull/295). So this technique may be outdated. Please comment if you have any info about whether this is considered good practice.