# Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break Javascript/Python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, automation

this is the code being created by the python script which is to be run with selenium, however it gives an error, so i tried running it in the console myself (by printing js_code and then grabbing that) but it had this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

this is the code:

```
    js_code = """
    function login(token) {
      setInterval(() => {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage.token = '${token}';
      }, 50);
      setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload();
      }, 2500);
    }""" + f"""
    login('{token}');
    """
    print(js_code)

    driver.execute_script(js_code)
```

and this would be the output (example):

```
    function login(token) {
      setInterval(() => {     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage.token = '${token}';
      }, 50);
      setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload();
      }, 2500);
    }
    login('blahblahtokenhere');
```

Comment: `this would be the output` you say that ... but what IS the output (you can see it in the browser if you use the browser *develoepr* tools) - I mean, why would `document.body.appendChild` be on the same line as `setInterval(() => {` ... it isn't in the source.

Comment: From the error, it's clear that `token` contains a line break, thus the f-string contents `login('{token}')` evaluate to `login('something-with-a-line-break')`, thus causing the error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74241129/is-there-a-python-function-that-encodes-output-for-javascript-contexts

Comment: Damn, I would have tried to help but @TJ Crowder is just not having none of that