# What type of document is HTML5?

Tags: xml, html

I know that XHTML is intended to be an XML-valid document (e.g., all tags are closed like `<br/>`). However, HTML5 is certainly not this way. What "type" of document is it?

In other words: is there a name for a document which is **"text and angle-bracket-enclosed tags with optional attributes, and which may optionally be closed"**?

Comment: Yes; it's called HTML.  (see also SGML)

Comment: So "<foo>&<bar></foo>" would be HTML? I feel like it's not....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml

Comment: HTML is based on SGML; XHTML is based on XML, not much more one could say about it.

Comment: @felipsmartins Thanks for the link, but as I've said already in my question, I am aware that HTML5 is not XML.

Comment: Html5 is html5, that's it

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) defines HTML5 as

> an **abstract language** for describing documents and applications, and some APIs for interacting with in-memory representations of resources that use this language.

This abstract language can be transmitted using different **concrete syntax**

- The first one is the HTML syntax associated with the `text/html` MIME type.
- The second one is the XHTML syntax which is an application of XML associated with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type.
- Another representation of this abstract language is the in-memory Document Object Model (DOM).