# Extracting the text of a html / css code in c#

Tags: c#, html, css

is it possible, to get the text relevant part of a formated html/css code?
I got this content:

```
<div class="ExternalClass0909250B34584AE5AA58772B3064DCD5">
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Solution (SO_)= lml</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Product (PR_)= slider</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Team (T_) = kehrberger</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Anforderer = renner</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Erfolgt ein FAK – Einsatz? Nein&#160; </p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Werksvertrag </p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Beistellung relevant?&#160; nein</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Anlieferadresse&#58;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Bürocampus Wangen - Kofi Warenannahme</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Joachim Renner (Daimler AG)</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Hedelfinger Str. 60</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">70327 Stuttgart</p>
</div>
```

When I just inserte this in the text window here, he displays this:

```
<div class="ExternalClass0909250B34584AE5AA58772B3064DCD5">
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Solution (SO_)= lml</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Product (PR_)= slider</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Team (T_) = kehrberger</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Anforderer = renner</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Erfolgt ein FAK – Einsatz? Nein&#160; </p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Werksvertrag </p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Beistellung relevant?&#160; nein</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">&#160;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;font-family&#58;calibri;font-size&#58;11pt;">Anlieferadresse&#58;</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Bürocampus Wangen - Kofi Warenannahme</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Max Mustermann (Company)</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">Musterstraße 60</p>
    <p style="margin&#58;0in;color&#58;black;font-family&#58;arial;font-size&#58;10pt;">12345 Musterstadt</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible in C# to get just the text as shown in the yellow box?

Thank you.

Comment: Just about anything is possible. Have you looked into libraries that understand HTML and tries to use them? What was the result of that?

Comment: You could also try using an XML parser. .NET has a few built in.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone [HTML is not XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml).

Comment: @mason You're absolutely correct. However, the example he gives is valid XHMTL. But yeah in general you need a parser that can handle the quirks of HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the Html Agility pack. Add it through Nuget. Once you have that you can do something like below

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);
HtmlNode myNode = doc.DocumentNode.FindNode(some xpath to select what you want);
```

now you can extract the text from myNode, children/parentnodes, or any of the attributes such as the styles, etc.

Comment: Yes, I found this answer very often. But I doesn't work in my case.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument MyDocument = new System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument() //ERROR: HtmlDocument doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: And the method "LoadHtml" is also not available.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Sorry. This is not the HtmlDocument of the namespace System.Windows.Forms....

Comment: sorry yes, you'll have to add "using HtmlAgilityPack;"

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search for "C# HTML Parser" yielded at least these two resources:

- The [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)
- [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

Please read the documentation, and come back here if you have specific errors you need help dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Its not actively maintained anymore, but you could try using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

I've had some luck with it in the past, doing similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much - it was a missunderstanding. In the most examples in the wwww, the used the HtmlDocument-Class. Such a Class is provided in the Lib System.Windows.Forms.
The examples used the Lib "HtmlAgilityPack" where the class has the same name.

My problem is solved - thank you all.