# c# substring - parse all text in between

Tags: c#, substring

trying to parse all text (mainly the url) from the html code below. but i would only like to grab the url between these div tags (result-firstline-title) and (result-url js-result-url) for each(all) occurrences.

to be clear, i am able to grab all the url from the html source below, but the problem is it is also grabbing the url almost 3 times. and for that i have a fix which to remove duplicate urls, however, if you look carefully to the html source, you will see that it also grabs the 3rd url.

```
<div class="result js-result card-mobile ">
<div class="result-firstline-container">
    <div class="result-firstline-title">
        <a
            class="result-title js-result-title"

            href="https://www.lifewire.com/top-social-networking-sites-people-are-using-3486554"

        >
            The Top Social Networking Sites People Are Using
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

<a
    class="result-url js-result-url"

    href="https://www.lifewire.com/top-social-networking-sites-people-are-using-3486554">https://www.lifewire.com/top-<b>social-networking-sites</b>-people-are...
</a>
<p class="result-snippet">
    The Top
</p>
</div>

<div class="result js-result card-mobile ">
    <div class="result-firstline-container">
        <div class="result-firstline-title">
            <a
                class="result-title js-result-title"

                href="http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking- websites"

            >
                Top 15 Most Popular Social Networking Sites | January 2019
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a
        class="result-url js-result-url"

        href="http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking- websites">www.ebizmba.com/articles/<b>social-networking</b>-<b>websites</b>
    </a>
    <p class="result-snippet">
        Top 15 Most 
    </p>

</div>
```

i have tried the following c# code to grab the text between the div tags but it grabs everything, which i dont want.

```
        int urlTagFrom = rawHTMLFromSource.IndexOf("result-firstline-title") + "result-firstline-title".Length;
        int urlTagTo = rawHTMLFromSource.LastIndexOf("result-url js-result-url");
        urlTagCollection = rawHTMLFromSource.Substring(urlTagFrom, urlTagTo - urlTagFrom);
```

to grab url i am using the following:

`var regexURLParser = new Regex(@"(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);`

what i want is to grab is the url from these:

```
        <a
            class="result-title js-result-title"

            href="https://www.lifewire.com/top-social-networking-sites-people-are-using-3486554"

        >

        <a
            class="result-title js-result-title"

            href="http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking-websites"

        >
```

so that the outcome shows only:

```
https://www.lifewire.com/top-social-networking-sites-people-are-using-3486554
http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking-websites
```

Comment: For the sake of humanity, [you might want to consider using a proper XML parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5623232).

Comment: Make your life a lot simpler, and use AngleSharp.

Comment: @NPras why XML? Am I missing something?

Comment: @sLw HTML is a variety of XML, therefore an XML parser is likely to simplify the solution to this problem.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, technically HTML isn't strict XML ([unlike XHTML, which is valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml)). But that example seems like a properly formed XML fragment, so a simple XML parser is likely to work. A HTML parser is likely heavier, and you'd need to rely on third-party code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it more easier by using  [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) just include it in your project using NuGet.

To add HTMLAgilityPack using NuGet

go to the `Package Manager Console` and type `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.11.3`

after the installation you can extract Urls like below.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"put html string here");

var listOfUrls = new List<string>();
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").ToList()
   .ForEach(x=> 
           {
              //Use HasClass method to filter elements 
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttributeValue("href", "")) 
                   && x.HasClass("result-title") && x.HasClass("js-result-title"))
              {
                 listOfUrls.Add(x.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
              }
           });

listOfUrls.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

**EDIT**

Added `&& x.HasClass("result-title") && x.HasClass("js-result-title")` to shows only those elements which has the class result-title and js-result-title.

**Another way**

shorter and another way to get filtered values.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"put html string here");

var listOfUrls = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null 
                && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "result-title js-result-title")
    .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("href", "")).ToList();
```

Comment: well, this method also grabs the 2nd url since it is in a href attribute. i only need the url after this (class="result-title js-result-title") tag.

Comment: @Buddhihin to filter element with class you can use `HasClass` method. Please see Edit.

Comment: thanks, i tried your 2nd method, it works. is doing this way faster than regex? also, are there other ways to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, there are other way to do the same, Regex can be a faster but not suitable for this. if you found this helpful then accept the answer so other can take benefits.